# Is it possible to achieve asynchronous processing when coding against a purely synchronous library?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, parallel-processing

I'm working with a library that doesn't provide async methods :

`Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser`

Is it possible to achieve "async like" results ?  e.g. multiple files processed in parallel where total time is much less than if processed sequentially

Or is it the case that in the absence of async substrate methods ( where most of the cpu-intensive work is performed ) it's not possible to take advantage of multiple cores ?

Comment: You may want to replace that old class with [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/), it provides async methods

Comment: You might find this interesting: [What is the difference between concurrency, parallelism and asynchronous methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844637/what-is-the-difference-between-concurrency-parallelism-and-asynchronous-methods)

Comment: I agree with using CsvHelper or *any* other parser except the VB one. That's legacy code,  added as a convenience class back in 2002. By today's standards, it's not convenient and can't handle the quirks you may encounter in various quasi-CSV files

Comment: Why do you want asynchronous processing in the first place? TextFieldParser is *very* slow. TextFieldParser was [7 times slower than CsvHelper back in 2020](https://www.joelverhagen.com/blog/2020/12/fastest-net-csv-parsers) and 15 times slower than Sep on a single core. You'll get far better performance than `Task.Run` simply by using a better parser. If you use [Sep with ParallelEnumerate](https://github.com/nietras/Sep) you'll get 40 times better performance

Comment: How do you use `TextFieldParser`? It's so slow it's not worth showing how to use it asynchronously. It's better to show how to convert your code to use CsvHelper or Sep to instantly get 7-15x better performance and *then* use these asynchronously with eg `Parallel.ForEachAsync` or `TransformBlock`.

Comment: The file size matters too. `Sep`'s `ParallelEnumerate` can speed up reading large files while `Parallel.ForEachAsync` will speed up reading multiple smaller files concurrently, using one core for each file.

Answer (score 0):

With [Task.Run(...)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run) you should be able to make any synchronous method into a async one.

```cs
public class Program
{
    // synchronous method
    public static double CalculatePI()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
        return Math.PI;
    }
    
    public static async Task Main()
    {
        var task1 = Task.Run(() => CalculatePI());
        var task2 = Task.Run(() => CalculatePI());
        var task3 = Task.Run(() => CalculatePI());
        
        var results = await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2, task3);
        
        Console.WriteLine(results[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: See [Should I expose asynchronous wrappers for synchronous methods?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/should-i-expose-asynchronous-wrappers-for-synchronous-methods/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible using `Task.Run`, Parallel.ForEach or pipeline classes like TransformBlock or Channels, but in this case it's not worth it. TextFieldParser is extremely slow. It's a legacy convenience class introduced in 2002 that's not very convenient by modern standards, nor can it handle quirky files.

Out of [41 CSV parsers](https://www.joelverhagen.com/blog/2020/12/fastest-net-csv-parsers), TextFieldParser is 39th. [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/), one of the most popular and full featured libraries is 7 times faster. The fastest single-threaded library (Sep) is 15 times faster and once you use parallelism, it's 30-40 times faster. Memory usage is a lot better too.

Using CsvHelper reading this file as a strongly-typed Foo class

```
Id,Name
1,one
2,two
```

is as simple as

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

...
using (var reader = new StreamReader("path\\to\\file.csv"))
using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
{
    var records = csv.GetRecords<Foo>();
    //Now process the records
    foreach(Foo record in records)
    {
    ...
    }
}
```

That alone is a lot faster than using TextFieldParser in parallel.

You can import files asynchronously if you use `GetRecordsAsync`. This returns an `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` that returns each record asynchronously.

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader("path\\to\\file.csv"))
using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
{
    var records = csv.GetRecordsAsync<Foo>();
    //Now process the records
    await foreach(Foo record in records)
    {
    ...
    }
}
```

With that, you can process multiple files concurrently :

```
var files=Directory.EnumerateFiles(folderPath,"*.csv");

await Parallel.ForEachAsync(files,async (file,cancellationToken)=>{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(file))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
        var records = csv.GetRecordsAsync<Foo>(cancellationToken);
        //Now process the records
        await foreach(Foo record in records)
        {
        ...
        }
    }    
});
```

or, with a bit of cleanup:

```
async Task ProcessFileAsync(string filePath,CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
        var records = csv.GetRecordsAsync<Foo>();
        //Now process the records
        await foreach(Foo record in records)
        {
        ...
        }
    }    
}
...
var files=Directory.EnumerateFiles(folderPath,"*.csv");
await Parallel.ForEachAsync(files,ProcessFileAsync);
```

Answer (score -3):

I would suggest trying to enclose the call to function/methods in the library within async Task <function_name> statement, if it supports parallel operation the function should run just fine