# Is there a simple example of benefits of async await in C#?

Tags: c#, async-await

Right now, I cannot understand the difference between async and sync code execution in an API.
I'd like to see an example of async await usage in C#, that would clearly show me why it's good.

I've tried to create a simple Console App project, that would simulate an API call.

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace TestAppConsole
{
    internal class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main()
        {
            var asyncProcessor = new AsyncDataProcessor();
            await asyncProcessor.ProcessDataAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestAppConsole
{
    public class AsyncDataProcessor
    {
        public async Task ProcessDataAsync()
        {
            var api1Data = await GetDataFromApi1Async();
            var api2Data = await GetDataFromApi2Async();
            
            var result = Process(api1Data, api2Data);
            
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }

        private async Task<string> GetDataFromApi1Async()
        {
            // Simulate an asynchronous API call
            await Task.Delay(2000);
            return "Data from API 1";
        }

        private async Task<string> GetDataFromApi2Async()
        {
            // Simulate another asynchronous API call
            await Task.Delay(2000);
            return "Data from API 2";
        }

        private string Process(string data1, string data2)
        {
            // Simulate data processing
            return $"Processed: {data1} and {data2}";
        }
    }
}
```

I thought that execution would take around 2s, but it still takes 4s, as in sync code.

Explain to me, please, how can I see the difference between async and sync code in WebAPI?
Or what I've done wrong in my example, so it runs sync instead of async?

Comment: It depends when you call `await`.
Try awaiting `Process(await api1Data, await api2Data);`  like this for example.

Comment: Now try it in a GUI app, and try do something while it's running the sync version. Note that parallelism and async are separate and orthogonal to each other.

Comment: Are you asking about the benefits of async/await in general, or about how to use the async/await for the specific purpose of implementing [concurrency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844637/what-is-the-difference-between-concurrency-parallelism-and-asynchronous-methods)? If you are asking for the later, then please edit the question and change the title to reflect what you really want to know. Like *"How to use async/await to make concurrent API calls"*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're currently waiting for `GetDataFromApi1Async` to complete before you call `GetDataFromApi2Async`. If you were to call both methods and then await the returned tasks, you'd see them run in parallel. For example:

```cs
public async Task ProcessDataAsync()
{
    // Somewhat dangerous - see notes below
    var api1Task = GetDataFromApi1Async();
    var api2Task = GetDataFromApi2Async();

    var api1Data = await api1Task;
    var api2Data = await api2Task;

    var result = Process(api1Data, api2Data);
    
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Now, this does have a problem - if both `api1Task` and `api2Task` end up faulted, you'll never see the `api2Task` failure. There are various ways of addressing that, but they're outside the scope of what you were asking.

There's much more to async than being able to have multiple calls in parallel though. That can be done with "normal" threading too. Async generally allows you to write that code more simply - but there are some complex aspects like the one above to be aware of. Asynchrony allows you to create a lot of asynchronous tasks *without* tying up threads, which a) allows a higher degree of parallelism without using that many threads; b) allows much simpler IO-based code for thread-sensitive scenarios such as WPF/WinForms user interfaces.

Comment: Can you, please, add an example of 
"a) allows a higher degree of parallelism without using that many threads;"
In a more simple API (Non-GUI) scenario and explain its benefits?

Comment: @donatellony: I'd rather not go into "answer creep" mode here. But fundamentally, imagine you were writing a web server which did very little work itself, but made requests to other services and just transformed the results. If you have 1000 requests per second, and each creates another request which takes a second, would you rather have 1000 active threads at the same time (each with its own stack in memory) or very, very few active threads at a time, just doing the actual work when a new request comes in or a response from the other service has completed?

Comment: thanks for the example :)
So, to better see the difference, I should write some kind of a benchmark, that would execute a lot of "ProcessDataAsync", right?

Comment: @donatellony: I'm not going to keep answering questions in comments that go beyond the original question. I suggest you do whatever research seems appropriate, and ask a new question if necessary.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you await the first call before you start the second one. The second call will be started after the first one has been finished. You can change this:

```
        public async Task ProcessDataAsync()
        {
            Task<string> api1task = GetDataFromApi1Async();
            Task<string> api2task = GetDataFromApi2Async();

            await Task.WhenAll(api1task, api2task);
            
            string api1result = await api1task;
            string api2result = await api2task;

            var result = Process(api1result , api2result );
            
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
```

This will result that the first task is started, and the second task is started immediately. When both tasks are started, the will be awaited, and this will lead to the expected performance gain.