# How is parallelism on a single thread/core possible?

Tags: language-agnostic, parallel-processing, computer-science

Modern programming languages provide parallelism and concurrency mechanisms as first class citizens to their users. I understand how parallel algorithms are programmed and can well imagine how two threads on a multi-core CPU can run in parallel.

Yet, most of these platforms also support running parallel processes on a single thread.

- Do these processes really run in parallel?
- How, on an assembly level can two different routines be executed simultaneously on a single thread?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

TLTR; : parallelism (in the sense of true **simultanenous** execution) on a single, non-hyperthreaded CPU core, is NOT possible.

---

**Hardware** (<- EDIT) Paralellism can be achieved at several levels. Ordered by decreasing granularity :

1. multi-host
2. multi-processor
3. multi-core
4. multi-threads ("Hyper-Threading", i.e. "HT")
   (EDIT: I voluntarity omit the case of vectorized compuations where several ALUs can be *driven* by the same core)

Your question relates to running two software threads in cases 3. (in case HT is unavailable / disabled) or 4.

- In both cases, the processes actually do NOT run in parallel. The user has an impression of simultaneity due to the extremely fast context switches performed at the CPU level, that tend to allocate, sequentially, the physical core (resp. thread) time to one or the other software thread
- In both cases, those routines are simply not executed simultaneously, but sequentially

The relative priority allocated to each of those 2 routines can be set on various OSes by the "Priority" you give to the process, that will be handled by the OS's scheduler, which in turn will allocate CPU time.

HTH.

To perform tests to better understand this topic, you may want to google "cpu affinity". This will let you run a two-threaded process on one physical single core of a multi-core CPU, and time the time taken by each of the threads, while modifying their priority, etc...

Comment: (4) mixes up two different things.  HT is hardware support to allow fast switching between two threads (so if one thread is waiting for data from memory, the other can take over).  there's also (5) which is "simple" threading on the software level.  both 4 and 5 are not "true" threading where the operations happen in parallel but (4) gets significantly closer, in that some operations (or partial operations) may occur in parallel with the other hyper-thread.  for example, memory fetching for one hyper-thread can be happening while the other runs.

Comment: @adrew cooke : thanks for refining the list. I intentionally did not include (5) in the list precisely because it is "software" parallelism, so you are right (and I'm modifying the initial post) : I was only listing "hardware" parallelism types.

Comment: -1: All modern CPUs provide parallelism at the instruction level. See my answer.

Comment: @JørgenFogh: superscalar / vector CPUs are particular kinds of CPUs. What you say does not contradict my argument, which is relative to "single, non-hyperthreaded CPU cores". If you wish I can add "non-vectorized, non-superscalar" :)

Comment: You're technically correct. However, *all* CPUs have had at least some parallelism at the instruction level for many years. Most programmers aren't targeting machines from the seventies.

Comment: @JørgenFogh: definitely but this question states "how two threads on a multi-core CPU can run in parallel." The parallelism you are mentioning does not allow to execute tow _threads_ in parallel, does it ?

Comment: True. I can't change my vote now, unless the question is edited though.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there *is* parallelism in each thread and you get it for free, no matter which programming language you use (although the amount of parallelism may vary).

It's called [instruction-level parallelism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_level_parallelism). The details are quite complex and differ between different processor micro-architectures.

[Computer Architecture: A Quantitative Approach](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0067KU84U) is a brilliant book which includes a chapter on instruction-level parallelism and the book's examples teach how to think rationally about engineering.

Check out the following links for more information:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superscalar

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_pipelining

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out-of-order_execution