# having problem making a multitask program to connect to an api

Tags: c#

I have a list of stocks and I want to go through the list and get the price for every one of them and I want it, the program isn't cpu intensive so I need it to get all prices within one minute it also saves to a text file as it processes

the api I'm using will allow me to make 10k connections per min so DDos wont be a problem

The pc I will be running this program on has only one cpu so multithreading isn't an option I don't think

so far this is the code I've created

it works somewhat good on my multicore computer but still not fast enough but not well on single core computers

```
   public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(Threads);
        t.Start();
    }
    private object acctLock = new object();
    static readonly object syncRoot = new object();

    private void Threads()
    {
        string filePathAccounts = "";
        if (radioButtonCarrierAccountsFile.Checked)
        {
            filePathAccounts = textBoxAccountsCarrier.Text;
        }

        List<string> stockList = File.ReadAllLines(filePathAccounts).ToList();
        int accountPosition = 0;
        int totalAccounts = stockList.Count;
        Parallel.ForEach(stockList.AsParallel(), new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Convert.ToInt32(textBoxThreads.Text) }, recipient =>
        {


            lock (acctLock)
            {
                string[] stockEntries = stockList[accountPosition].Split(',');
                // This creates an array so we can add each line to its own variable
                stock = stockList[Convert.ToInt32(0)];
                ++accountPosition;
            }

            // connecto to api and get info
            string stockPrice = "Price received from api json";
                lock (acctLock)
                {
                    StreamWriter appendToFile = new StreamWriter("stockPrice.txt", true);
                    appendToFile.WriteLine($"{stock},{stockPrice}");
                    appendToFile.Dispose();
                }


        });
    }
```

Comment: a) The `lock` inside the `.ForEach` imho defeats the parallellism. b) Single core and parallelism are [kinda hard/impossible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10245337/how-is-parallelism-on-a-single-thread-core-possible)

Comment: Also, each ForEach iteration opens, writes and closes a file. That's expensive.

Comment: You should focus on _async I/O_ rather than on multi-threading. I don't think this mock-up is a good starting point for doing so.

Comment: Yes I understand this won't work for what I want to achieve and I don't know how to implement async I/O into my project

Comment: You are closing the file after writing one line, then opening file and moving to end of file, then repeat sequence.   No wonder code is slow.  How big is the text file?

Comment: by the time the program finishes the text file that its opening and closing will have 8k symbols stock entries and prices

text file wont be over 200kb after its finished

Comment: Fixed that with File.AppendAllText($"settings\\sentTo.txt", stocks + Environment.NewLine);