# Conflicting things about redis working: Is redis single threaded or multithreaded?

Tags: redis

In this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17099222/are-redis-operations-on-data-structures-thread-safe/17099452#17099452) , it is given that **REDIS IS SINGLE THREADED**. But in this [link](https://redis.io/commands/unlink), it is given that

> "the command performs the actual memory reclaiming in a **different
>   thread**, so it is **not blocking**"

So what is the point? Will redis block a command until the previous command is completed or it is actually multi-threaded?

Comment: please have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10495458/1530987)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redis actually uses several threads. It is not really "multi-threaded" though because it uses a single thread to answer requests.

here is a multi-threaded port of Redis.
https://github.com/grisha/thredis
But it comes with some limitations e.g. it can't be used as a replication master.

Comment: You say it uses single thread to answer requests. By this you mean, only one command gets executed once. Which in turn means, redis blocks the execution of other commands until the current command is completed. But the UNLINK command seem to not block other commands. This is what I find contradicting.

Comment: It marks the keys as deleted in the main 'answering' thread but then another thread will do the memory clean up in the background. So the main thread is blocked for the least amount of time while another thread does the bulk of the work in a nonblocking way

Comment: @Chris Tanner Thank you