# redis block until key exists

Tags: python, asynchronous, redis, python-asyncio

I'm new to Redis and was wondering if there is a way to be able to `await` `get`ing a value by it's key until the key exists. Minimal code:

```
async def handler():
    data = await self._fetch(key)

async def _fetch(key):
    return self.redis_connection.get(key)
```

As you know, if such `key` doesnt exist, it `return`'s `None`. But since in my project, `set`ing key value pair to redis takes place in another application, I want the redis_connection `get` method to block untill key exists.
Is such expectation even valid?

Comment: Does it have to be immediate? Could you sleep(1) on your _fetch() method until the key is available?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not possible to do what you are trying to do without implementing some sort of polling **redis GET** on your client. On that case your client would have to do something like:

```
async def _fetch(key):
    val = self.redis_connection.get(key)
    while val is None:
       # Sleep and retry here
       asyncio.sleep(1)  
       val = self.redis_connection.get(key)
    return val
```

However I would ask you to completelly reconsider the pattern you are using for this problem.
It seems to me that what you need its to do something like Pub/Sub https://redis.io/topics/pubsub.

So the app that performs the **SET** becomes a publisher, and the app that does the **GET** and waits until the key is available becomes the subscriber.

I did a bit of research on this and it looks like you can do it with asyncio_redis:

- Subscriber https://github.com/jonathanslenders/asyncio-redis/blob/b20d4050ca96338a129b30370cfaa22cc7ce3886/examples/pubsub/receiver.py.
- Sender(Publisher): https://github.com/jonathanslenders/asyncio-redis/blob/b20d4050ca96338a129b30370cfaa22cc7ce3886/examples/pubsub/sender.py

Hope this helps.

Comment: the code your provided is exactly what I've done. thanks for the information though.

Answer (score 4):

Except the **keyspace notification** method mentioned by @Itamar Haber, another solution is the blocking operations on `LIST`.

1. `handler` method calls `BRPOP` on an empty `LIST`: `BRPOP notify-list timeout`, and blocks until `notify-list` is NOT empty.
2. The other application pushes the value to the `LIST` when it finishes setting the key-value pair as usual: `SET key value; LPUSH notify-list value`.
3. `handler` awake from the blocking operation with the value you want, and the `notify-list` is destroyed by Redis automatically.

The advantage of this solution is that you don't need to modify your `handler` method too much (with the keyspace notification solution, you need to register a callback function). While the disadvantage is that you have to rely on the notification of another application (with keyspace notification solution, Redis does the notification automatically).

Answer (score 3):

The closest you can get to this behavior is by enabling [keyspace notifications](https://redis.io/topics/notifications) and subscribing to the relevant channels (possibly by pattern).

Note, however, that notifications rely on PubSub that is not guaranteed to deliver messages (at-most-once semantics).

Answer (score 2):

After Redis 5.0 there is built-in stream which supports blocking read. The following are sample codes with [redis-py](https://redis-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#redis.Redis.xread).

```
#add value to my_stream
redis.xadd('my_stream',{'key':'str_value'})

#read from beginning of stream
last_id='0'

#blocking read until there is value
last_stream_item = redis.xread({"my_stream":last_id},block=0) 

#update last_id
last_id = last_stream_item[0][1][0][0]

#wait for next value to arrive on stream 
last_stream_item = redis.xread({"my_stream":last_id},block=0)
```