# Is there any ways to evict keys from Redis just after accessing it?

Tags: redis, spring-data, spring-data-redis

As per this answer [https://stackoverflow.com/a/17099452/8804776][1]

> "You might not know it, but Redis is actually single-threaded, which
>   is how every command is guaranteed to be atomic. While one command is
>   executing, no other command will run."

Redis is single threaded. My requirement is to store a key in Redis and as soon as a thread access it it should evict.

eg:
   HSET bucket-1 name justin

Thread A and B accessing the same key
   HGET bucket-1 name
Only one thread should get the data at any given point.

Is there any particular settings that i can do to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term "eviction" refers to keys that have an expiry set (TTL). While there is no dedicated command to achieve what you want, you can use a transaction such as:

```
WATCH bucket-1
HGET bucket-1 name
(pseudo: if not nil)
MULTI
HDEL bucket-1 name
EXEC
```

If the `EXEC` fails it means you're in thread B (assuming that A got there first).

Alternatively, the above can be compacted into an idiomatic Lua script - as suggested by @The_Dude - such as (*newlines added for readability*):

```
EVAL "local v=redis.call('HGET', KEYS[1], ARGV[1])
      redis.call('HDEL', KEYS[1], ARGS[1])
      return v" 
      1 bucket-1 name
```

A `nil` reply means you're B.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a command to do that with hashes. You could use a Lua script to handle this.

You could also use [GETSET](https://redis.io/commands/getset) instead, where you can reset a key to a value that denotes it has been used by another consumer.

Comment: Even this answer also will help if I'm going with SET instead of HSET