# Redis Queue use with django web app running on apache multi threads

Tags: django, multithreading, web, redis

I was going through redis queue documentation at [redis docs](http://python-rq.org/docs/), but could not find info on how the queue handles en-queue calls from parallel threads of web server in the context of which it gets called. Any details are highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Redis in single threaded.  It handles once request after another.  Does that answer your question?

This seems to be a bit of a duplicate
[Redis is single-threaded, then how does it do concurrent I/O?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10489298/redis-is-single-threaded-then-how-does-it-do-concurrent-i-o)

Comment: Ok, what if multiple threads of web server try to en-queue jobs to the same queue(when it gets parallel requests from multiple web clients) . Does Redis ensure that the concurrency is maintained? or somehow the web-app needs to manage concurrency?