# Redis SortedSet: Does the ZUNIONSTORE command block other concurrency commands?

Tags: concurrency, redis

I want to create a temporary sorted-set based on the origin one in a timer, maybe the interval is 4 hour, I'm using spring-data-redis api to do this.

```
ZUNIONSTORE tmp 2 A B AGGREGATE MAX
```

when the `ZUNIONSTORE` commmand is executing, will it block any other commands like 
`ZADD`,`ZREM`,`ZRANGE`,`ZINCRBY` based on the SortedSet A or B ? I don't know if this will cause 
`concurrency problems`, please give me some suggestions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Redis is single-threaded, then how does it do concurrent I/O?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10489298/redis-is-single-threaded-then-how-does-it-do-concurrent-i-o)

Comment: Probably duplicate - in any case, since Redis is (mostly) single threaded, it only performs one command at a time so any other commands are blocked during execution.