# Async Servlets not executing the async task in a separate thread

Tags: java, servlets, asynchronous, spring-boot, nio

I am exploring async servlets using Spring boot. As far as I understand, async servlets are used to execute long running tasks in a thread other than the one which container launches to handle the request, so that container can use its own thread for handling other connections. Based on this understanding, I tried the following code:

```
@WebServlet(asyncSupported = true, urlPatterns = "/demo")
@Component
public class demo extends HttpServlet {



    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
     *      response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        final AsyncContext context = request.startAsync();
        ServletOutputStream stream = response.getOutputStream();
        WriteListener listener = new WriteListener() {

            @Override
            public void onWritePossible() throws IOException {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId());
                ServletOutputStream output = context.getResponse().getOutputStream();
                if (output.isReady()) {
                    try {
                        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    output.print("Heloooooooooo");
                }
                context.complete();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
                throwable.printStackTrace(System.err);
                context.complete();
            }
        };

        stream.setWriteListener(listener);
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId());

    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
     *      response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,
            IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

But the problem is that `onWritePossible` method is being invoked by the same thread which ran `doGet`. Shouldn't it have been different ?

Comment: Typically, there will be two requests. One for the main page and another for the websocket (fired by javascript once the page loads)

Comment: This isn't about websockets . It's an Async Servlet and i am trying to access it via http://localhost:8080/demo

Answer (score 1):

In your `doGet` method you have created an `AsyncContext` and it is your responsibility to pass it further to a different thread that will (at a later time) complete the processing by setting the result - servlet container will not create a new thread for you.

After `AsyncContext` is passed to a different thread, `doGet` can immediately return freeing up the servlet container's executor thread to serve new requests.

An example based on your code:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    final AsyncContext context = request.startAsync();
    System.out.println("Servlet container thread before async started: " 
        + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
                try {
                    System.out.println("New thread started: " 
                         + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                    ServletOutputStream output = context.getResponse().getOutputStream();
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);
                    System.out.println("New thread writing response: " 
                        + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                    output.print("Hi!");
                    context.complete();
                } catch (Throwable e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
    }).start();
    System.out.println("Servlet container thread returning: " 
        + Thread.currentThread().getName());
}
```

Output:

```
Servlet container thread before async started: http-nio-8080-exec-1
Servlet container thread returning: http-nio-8080-exec-1
New thread started: Thread-3
New thread writing response: Thread-3
```

If you use Spring Boot, you can implement a `Controller` which returns a `Callable` and Spring Framework will make sure that the `Callable` is executed in a different thread whose lifecycle is managed by Spring.

If you want to do it without Spring (which is also fine), it is typically done by placing the `AsyncContext` in the queue and having an `ExecutorService` consuming the queued requests.

Answer (score -1):

Your understanding is a bit off.  The benefit of async methods as they're typically used is to *not* consume an additional thread, while also *not* blocking the thread handling the request.  To get any real benefit out of them, you need to utilize non-blocking API's when performing IO.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31899407/is-my-understanding-of-async-await-how-it-works-and-its-benefits-correct), while asked in the context of .NET technologies, should shed some light.