# Twitter-clone Redis global post id

Tags: php, twitter, redis

I am looking at the [doc](http://redis.io/topics/twitter-clone) of design and implementation of a simple Twitter clone using PHP and the Redis key-value store. I found that the `next_post_id` variable is global.

I am wondering why not every user keeps his own `next_post_id`, and the user's `next_post_id` and his `user_id` can identify a unique post. In this case, we can reduce the contention on updating `next_post_id` in simultaneous accesses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redis demands keeping things as simple as possible.

Post identifier is increased globally because it's conceptually *global* too. Each user doesn't own a collection of posts, but posts are a global collection and they're assigned to *users*.

Using `incr` command each process connecting to Redis will get an unique post identifier, thus, there's no problem here with this strategy.

> In this case, we can reduce the contention on updating next_post_id in simultaneous accesses

This isn't true, because Redis isn't multi-threaded when reading and writing to a database. It's single-threaded. That is, **there're no simultaneous accesses, but *sequential accesses***. You should realize, then, that there would be no benefit on doing what you said.

Maybe you want to take a look at this other Q&A: [Redis is single-threaded, then how does it do concurrent I/O?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10489298/redis-is-single-threaded-then-how-does-it-do-concurrent-i-o)