# Am I guaranteed that the requests to Redis will be executed in order?

Tags: redis

all.  I write a data item to Redis.  Then later, I read the data item out of Redis.

Since there may be multiple servers taking these Redis requests and satisfying them, if I make the write request 1 ms before I make the read request (suppose they're both being done by the same process) am I assured that the read request won't be processed first, and I get a response back like "that data item doesn't exist"?

Answer (score 0):

<s>Assuming that the commands are being issued in sequence, you can assume that they will be atomic and single-threaded operations. Read more about this in [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10489298/redis-is-single-threaded-then-how-does-it-do-concurrent-i-o).</s>

The above is True for a single Redis server, and not guaranteed for a Cluster behavior (thanks @mwp). In that situation, I'd recommend adding a check at the client level. If key doesn't exist when Redis makes its GET call, by default a [nil value is returned](http://redis.io/commands/get).

Last note: depending on your implementation you may want to look into storing your redis items in a list, LPUSH-ing the write requests and BRPOP-ing the out values so you would always be guaranteed a value exists...

Comment: Yes, but here's clearly asking about Redis Cluster, or some kind of Redis cluster, so the rules that govern a single single-threaded instance of Redis may or may not apply here.

Comment: @mwp: Oh shoot, you are quite right. I missed that part of the question.

Comment: Hmm.  Thanks for the insights.  I will go and read up on LPUSH and BRPOP.  If I had paid more attention in geography class when I was a little faun, I might know those places.  I am using Heroku's RedisCloud.  So I really have no idea what they're doing behind the scenes.  They encourage you to think of it as "your Redis database" so I hope their infrastructure supports that illusion.