# Redis commands synchronous or asynchronous?

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis

AFAIK redis is a single threaded and its uses event loop under the hood. I would want to understand 2 things:

1. are all redis commands synchronous?
2. if they are asynchronous

```
  SET mykey "Hello" (first command)
  GET mykey (second command)
```

there is a possibility for the second command to return nil, if the set command isn't executed yet. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Redis is single-threaded , which means all commands should be atomic. For details

In your above example; If  the SET command gets to executed first then GET command will wait until SET completion; if GET command gets to executed first then then it will return nil and SET will subsequently be executed. so each command execution is atomic.

refer documentation; https://redis.io/topics/faq.

ps: for redis4.0 there is some multi-threading capability;  refer documentation for details

Comment: Meaning a GET command in this case is actually blocking if the SET command is not completed yet?

Comment: Yes; since redis is single threaded it accepts commands in sequential fashion and executes them atomically.

Comment: You can refer to this thread as well for details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48035646/if-redis-is-single-threaded-how-can-it-be-so-fast?rq=1