# How do Lua scripts block the entire Redis server?

Tags: java, redis, spring-data-redis

Let's say I have a Redis instance running and I have two clients A and B connected to it. I execute a read only operations LUA script from one of them and from the other a read only hash operation by using the Redis template in Java. Since all operations in Redis are blocking I assume that if the LUA script is issued first, the other client has to wait until the Lua script operation is finished. In the same way, if the hash operation is issued first, the Lua script operation has to wait until the hash operation is finished. Is this a valid statement? how does Redis handle calls from multiple sources if it's single threaded?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redis is single-threaded, then how does it do concurrent I/O?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10489298/redis-is-single-threaded-then-how-does-it-do-concurrent-i-o)

Answer (score 0):

Redis has an internal Even Loop that runs a single event on the main thread each time for more details see:

1. https://redis.io/topics/internals-rediseventlib
2. http://nosqlgeek.blogspot.com/2019/10/so-what-exactly-is-event-loop.html