# Game player matching algorithm (System Design)

Tags: redis, concurrency, system-design

Let's say we want to design a gaming platform for chess and our userbase is ~50M. And whenever a player comes to our platform to play chess we assign a random player with almost the same rating as an opponent. Every player has 4 level rating [Easy, Medium, Hard, Expert].

My approach was to keep all user in Redis cache(assume all users/boats are live and waiting for the opponent) so we are keeping data in the below format:

```
"chess:easy" : [u1, u2, u3]
"chess:medium" : [u4, u5, u6]
```

so when a user comes I will remove a user from the cache and assign.

```
For example: u7 (easy) wants to play chess games then his opponent will be u1(easy).
```

But won't this create a problem for **concurrent requests** as we read then remove from Redis List that will be blocking?

Can anyone suggest a better approach with or without cache?

Answer (score 1):

> But won't this create a problem for concurrent requests as we read then remove from Redis List that will be blocking?

No, because Redis is single-threaded when [it performs write](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10495458/3309466) but, assuming the 50M users are equality distributed across the chess level, you would get 4 lists, one per difficulty, with a length of 12,5 million

Manipulating the list could have a lot of complexity because using [`LPOP`][1] to select a user and remove it has `O(N)` complexity and the last user may wait a lot of time before getting an opponent.

I think you should aim to use a [HASH](https://redis.io/commands#hash) data structure and splitting the users in [different databases](https://redis.io/commands/select):

- db0: Easy
- db1: Medium
- db2: Hard
- db3: Expert

In this way, you can store the users that want to play with `HSET <USERID> status "ready to play"` and then benefit the [`RANDOMKEY`](https://redis.io/commands/randomkey) command to select an opponent and delete it with `HDEL <KEY RETURNED BY RANDOM> status`.

Doing so, you will execute commands `O(1)` only, providing a fast and reliable matching system that you can optimize further with the [redis pipeling](https://redis.io/topics/pipelining) feature.

NB: if you set and hash per difficulty level and adding multiple `fields` to the hash, you will hit the `O(N)` complexity due to the [`HDEL`](https://redis.io/commands/hdel) command!
[1]: https://redis.io/commands/lpop

> Can anyone suggest a better approach with or without cache?

There are many algorithms you may use such as:

- [Stable marriage problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_marriage_problem)
- [Exact cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_cover)

but it depends on the user experience you want to implement for your clients.
You can explore the [`gamedev.stackexchange.com` community](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matchmaking)