# google_oauth2_client how to handle 'Access denied'

Tags: dart

Following the tutorial on [DartWatch blog](http://blog.dartwatch.com/2013/04/sign-in-with-google-using-google-oauth2.html) on using Google OAuth library. The question is how to handle: 'Access denied' error from Google ?

Here is my code example:

```dart
class Client
{

   GoogleOAuth2 _auth;

   Client()
   {
      _auth = new GoogleOAuth2(
                        '5xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com', // Client ID
                        ['openid', 'email', 'profile'],
                        tokenLoaded:oauthReady);
   }

   void doLogin()
   {
       //    _auth.logout();
       //    _auth.token = null;
       try
       {
           _auth.login();
       }
       on AuthException {
           print('Access denied');
       }
       on Exception catch(exp)
       {
           print('Exception $exp occurred');
       }
   }

   void oauthReady(Token token)
   {
      print('Token is: $token');
   }          
}
```

but I never hit `catch` block on any (!) exception. What I'm doing wrong ?

I'm using:
   **Dart Editor version 0.5.0_r21823**
   **Dart SDK version 0.5.0.1_r21823**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never hit the catch block because `auth.login` is an asynchronous operation which returns a Future.

There is a [great article on Future error handling on the `dartlang.org` website](http://www.dartlang.org/articles/futures-and-error-handling/).

`auth.login` [returns a Future](https://github.com/dart-gde/dart-google-oauth2-library/blob/master/lib/src/browser/googleoauth2.dart#L98) immediately, but the work it does happens after control returns to the event loop (see [my answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16115298/launching-multiple-async-futures-in-response-to-events/16117949#16117949) for more on the event loop.)

Your code should look more like:

```dart
/// Returns a Future that completes to whether the login was successful.
Future<boolean> doLogin()
{
    _auth.login()
    .then((_) {
       print("Success!");
       return true;
    }.catchError((e) {
       print('Exception $e occurred.');
       return false; // or throw the exception again.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks :)  I forgot that `_auth.Login()` is a `Future`