# No top-level method 'spawnFunction' declared

Tags: dart

I'm trying to use Isolates in Dart. The tutorials from dartlang.org seem to use the function `spawnFunction`. But that does not seem to work for me. And I cant find any docs about this.

```
import 'dart:isolate';

void doThing() {
  print('Hello!');
}

main() {
  spawnFunction(doThing);
}
```

.

```
Unhandled exception:
No top-level method 'spawnFunction' declared.
```

The docs from [api.dartlang.org](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_isolate/Isolate.html) mention `Isolate.spawn` but I get an error saying there is no static method `spawn` declared.

Did I miss something? A link to appropriate docs (if any) would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isolate.spawn is indeed the new way of creating isolates. Your example would need to be rewritten as:

```
import 'dart:isolate';

void doThing(_) {
  print("Hello!");
}

main() {
  Isolate.spawn(doThing, null);
}
```

See https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!topic/misc/EVUMkZXFXtY for the breaking change announcement.