# Saving scoped object outside scope in Dart

Tags: dart, dart-async

The following leaves s null after the file read exits:

```dart
String s;
new File('etc.stk').readAsString().then((String contents) {
    s = contents;
});
// s is null here.
```

Is there a way to save (or clone) s, or am I compelled to use it only in the .then scope?

I have a few thousand lines of compiler/interpreter code that parses and runs the file contents, and would prefer not to have them all inside the new File scope.

**EDIT**

To provide more context, what I am trying to do is something like

```dart
new File('etc1.stk').readAsString()
    .then((String script) {     
      syntaxTree1 = buildTree(script);
    });
new File('etc2.stk').readAsString()
    .then((String script) {
      syntaxTree2 = buildTree(script);
    });
```

and have access to both syntaxTree1 and syntaxTree2 in subsequent code. I will wrap my mind around the Dart Way if I can.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT**
(this code is tested)

```dart
import 'dart:async' as async;
import 'dart:io' as io;

void main(args) {
// approach1: inline
  async.Future.wait([
     new io.File('file1.txt').readAsString(),
     new io.File('file2.txt').readAsString()
  ]).then((values) {
    values.forEach(print);
  });

// approach2: load files in another function
  getFiles().then((values) {
    values.forEach(print);
  });
}

async.Future<List> getFiles() {
  return async.Future.wait([
     new io.File('file1.txt').readAsString(),
     new io.File('file2.txt').readAsString()
  ]);
}
```

output:

> file1
> file2
>
> file1
> file2

**EDIT END**

hint: the code is not tested

```dart
// s is null here
```

is because this line is executed before

```dart
s = contents
```

This code

```dart
new File('etc.stk').readAsString()
```

returns a future that is enlisted in the event queue and is executed when the actual 'thread' of execution is finished.

If you had provided more code I would have a better context for a proposed solution.
What you could do is

```dart
String s;
new File('etc.stk').readAsString().then((String contents) {
    s = contents;
}).then((_) {
// s is **NOT** null here.
});
```

or

```dart
//String s;
new File('etc.stk').readAsString().then((String contents) {
    //s = contents;
    someCallback(s)
});
// s is null here.

void someCallback(String s) {
  // s is **NOT** null here
}
```

or

```dart
Future<String> myReadAsString() {
  return new File('etc.stk').readAsString();
}

myReadAsString().then((s) {
  // s is **NOT** null here
}
```

see also:

- https://www.dartlang.org/slides/2013/06/dart-streams-are-the-future.pdf
- [async programming in dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13507562/)
- https://www.dartlang.org/docs/tutorials/#futures
- https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart:async
- https://www.dartlang.org/articles/event-loop/
- https://www.dartlang.org/articles/futures-and-error-handling/

and maybe

- https://www.dartlang.org/articles/creating-streams/

Comment: Thanks @Günter, I think suggestions 1 or 3 might be what I am looking for. To provide more context, what I am trying to do is read in multiple files, process them into separate syntax trees, and still have access to the trees after the read block is done. I think I didn't quite realize what "done" meant. I will try to follow the Dart Way.

Comment: I added your comment to your question and updated my answer with an example that I have actually tested.