# How the operating system deals with applications that demands multiple actions

Tags: multithreading, process, operating-system

I'm studying operating systems and I have this doubt in my head for almost a whole week, and I couldn't find the answer in the book (Operating System Concepts - Silberschatz).
The question is how the operating system deals with a process that demands many actions to be executed? e.g. To play a video in a computer, the video must be processed, the audio must be processed, the video have to be sent to the monitor (I/O operation), the audio must be sent to the audio box (I/O operation) and so on.

In a computer with a single CPU the book says that a processor can run only one process at a time, so to process the video the operating system would have one thread for each of the operations listed before, the question is how does the operational system executes them? (Linux or Windows) Does it execute each one at a time and interchanges them (processes the video, send it to monitor monitor, processes the audio, send to audio to audio box and so on) but do it so fast that it is imperceptible or does it executes them concurrently (process the audio and video at the same time)? I think my main doubt in this question can translated as "Can two threads execute concurrently in a single CPU computer?"

Any correction and clarification in my understanding of the concepts is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does it execute each one at a time and interchanges them (processes the video, send it to monitor monitor, processes the audio, send to audio to audio box and so on) but do it so fast that it is imperceptible or does it executes them concurrently (process the audio and video at the same time)?

It switches between them fast enough to be imperceptible. On modern operating systems, this is done in three main ways:

- [Preemption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preemption_(computing)), where the task is simply suspended by the OS kernel's scheduler to run a different process. This is typically done when a fixed amount of time, called a *time slice*, runs out.
- When a process starts to wait for IO, from the network, from disk or from most other sources, many operating systems will suspend it immediately. That process will only resume running when the results of the IO are available.
- [Cooperative multitasking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Co-operative_multitasking#Cooperative_multitasking.2Ftime-sharing), when a process indicates to the OS that it is willing to wait.

The details are different on each OS, and very different between desktop OSs, server OS, and embedded and real-time OSs.

> Can two threads execute concurrently in a single CPU computer?

Check out this SO question on [concurrency vs. parallelism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050222/concurrency-vs-parallelism-what-is-the-difference).

Comment: Also note that many I/O operations are much slower than the CPU could execute them, so from a human perspective, the devices receive a steady, constant stream of samples (except when the system is under heavy load for unrelated reasons).