# How to run Three do while loops simultaneously inside one do while loop?

Tags: c

I have a program that minimizes the energy of a system by varying displacement `x[i]` in x-dimension using a `do while` condition loop. I want to extend it to a program that minimizes the energy by varying `x[i]`, `y[i]`, `z[i]`, I suppose, in this case three simultaneous `do while` loops are needed inside one big `do while` loop, how can I accomplish this?

Code for problem in one dimension is as shown below:

```
int main(void)
{
  double eta,energyold;
  energyold=1.0;
  unsigned i,j;
  init();

  do{
    function();
    functiond(); //JACOBIAN
    dgesv(fnd,b,N,dx);
    newpsn();
    energyT();
    eta=fabs(energy-energyold)/energy;
    energyold=energy;
    //printf("%lf %lf %lf\n",eta,energy,norm);
  }while(norm>1e-12);

  for(i=0;i<N;i++)
  {
     printf("The  Equillibrium position of ion %d is: %lf\n",i+1,x[i]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You might want to read about [threads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_%28computing%29)?

Comment: Current versions of C can't do that out of the box, you'd need extensions from your OS or you could try OpenMP, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP.

Comment: Also please indent your code properly when posting here, and have something that compiles without warnings: `main` has a return type of `int`.

Answer (score 2):

There are many suggestions to use threads, but I'm not convinced that you really need to.

This sounds more like a pure computational problem, where using threads on a multi-core CPU might cut down the total execution time, but isn't necessary in order to express the computation.

Can't you just use three nested loops (if you need to check all combinations of x/y/z values), or do them one at a time? Thread programming can be rather tricky, so it can be really "worth" avoiding if it's not really necessary for a particular problem.

Comment: My thoughts exactly. He doesn't need threads at all to explore 3D space. +1

Comment: If you just need to go through every grid-point on a 3D x-y-z grid, you can just nest 3 for-loops: `for (x in x-grid) { for (y in y-grid) { for (z in z-grid) { do_calculation(x,y,z); } } }` As a one-liner this looks messy. Just expand and you'll see :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can try using multithreading. Multithreading does not make your `do-while` loops to run parallely but concurrently.

If you are working on Linux, you can use `pthread` library which provide functions for spawning a new thread, assigning task scheduling method, mutexes related functions, etc.

**Some Useful Links:**

- [Threads tutorial 1](http://www.cs.nmsu.edu/~jcook/Tools/pthreads/pthreads.html)
- [Threads tutorial 2](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialPosixThreads.html)
- [`pthread` header and functions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread.h.html)
- `man pthread` (on Linux, if pthread library is installed)

Comment: "parallel" and "concurrent" mean the same thing. You were looking for "sequentially".

Comment: @BartFriederichs That's not how the term is often used, concurrency means they *might* be executed in parallel but there's no guarantee. Processes on a single-core CPU running a multi-tasking OS are concurrent, but of course not parallel; there is only one CPU. See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrent_computing).

Comment: @BartFriederichs : No it is not like that. Please see [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050222/concurrency-vs-parallelism-what-is-the-difference)