# Why is "Using asynchronous [...] methods on CPU-bound [providing] no benefits and results in more overhead."

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

I came accross this [article](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4). And under "Choosing Synchronous or Asynchronous Action Methods" the author states that you should not use asyncronous action methods when:

> The operations are primarily CPU operations instead of operations that involve extensive disk or network overhead. **Using asynchronous action methods on CPU-bound operations provides no benefits and results in more overhead.**

I do not understand why that would be so. Because if I have a method calculating the fibonacci numbers that takes up 30 seconds of computation that call is primarily CPU bound. Not making this async would block the calling thread for 30 seconds and make the application unresponsive.

Could you help me out with that reasoning?

Comment: Let me explain to you http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82499/room-for-aron-and-funkypeanut

Answer (score 8):

> Not making this async would block the calling thread for 30 seconds
>   and make the application unresponsive.

You're confusing [Concurrency and Parallelism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050222/concurrency-vs-parallelism-what-is-the-difference). The author is talking about taking advantage of **IO bound** operations using `async-await`, where you can free calling threads while they're doing IO work such as a network or a database call, instead of blocking them synchronously until that operation completes.

What you're talking about is executing **CPU bound** work on background threads. In the context of ASP.NET, you're executing work on a dedicated thread that was allocated by the Thread-Pool. There is no use in spinning up a new thread just to do CPU bound work. For that, you can simply execute on the thread which is currently executing.

Also, using `Task.Run` in ASP.NET is considered dangerous. You should only off-load work with objects that register their work with the runtime environment, such as the [`BackgroundTaskManager`](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AspNetBackgroundTasks).

If this were a UI app and you had a CPU bound operation, then deferring work to a background thread would be a valid thing to do, using `Task.Run`.

Comment: The question is regarding ASP.Net, also check the link.

Comment: @Aron I saw that it's about ASP.NET. I was just giving an example regarding the UI thread.

Comment: Its confusing. The question is about ASP.Net and why you SHOULD NOT use Task.Run. Which is correct advise. You should NEVER do it. Because there is no UI thread. There is no responsiveness issue. You would be just passing off work to another thread pool thread.

Comment: The OP's statement is misleading: "Not making this async would block the calling thread for 30 seconds and make the application unresponsive." This wouldn't matter all that much in a WebServer, although you'd probably want to cache the results after the 1st pass.

Comment: @Aron I see why you said that. I've updated my answer to reflect the specifics of ASP.NET.

Comment: True. But it's because the OP is confused.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov just want to clarify how to do you differentiate (or identify) that operations are   network-bound or I/O-bound or  CPU-bound.or let me put like this if you want to fetch around 3000 records from DB by joining around 8 tables and i want to use async call to fetch these records using linq , so will it be a good thing or is it a cpu bound operation ?

Answer (score 0):

Async programming is actually pretty vague to a lot of developers,me included.I always thought that async programming is concurrent,not parallel. Which means that we utilize it's waiting time in order to do something else and have the feel it is parallel. In reality however I stumbled upon this video couple of days ago.Link to video -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=il9gl8MH17s&lc=UgydFEXyhyXe7iAeR5J4AaABAg.9NxtCJSI5xK9O-YwEIp2KR
It goes quite in depth with the state machine looked in CIL.But what we are interested is the part where he shows that the first thread is actually busy spinning one loop.Time stamp is 7:50. You can clearly see that while the one thread was blocked now and the waiting time was over in the KettleBoiling method,the method actually finished while the one thread was looping.He then checks to see the thread ID's and indeed. The .NET spawned a totally new thread for the function's completion.I've talked with the developer and he said that you don't know if it will be concurrent or parallel.The optimization will be done if needed.I will definitely do some more researching on this part but for now this is the best guide I can give.So having this knowledge (for now) I would say that it isn't actually hurting performance for CPU bound tasks.

EDIT** This is something that I found from Microsoft :
If you have any I/O-bound needs (such as requesting data from a network, accessing a database, or reading and writing to a file system), you'll want to utilize asynchronous programming. You could also have CPU-bound code, such as performing an expensive calculation, which is also a good scenario for writing async code.

C# has a language-level asynchronous programming model, which allows for easily writing asynchronous code without having to juggle callbacks or conform to a library that supports asynchrony. It follows what is known as the Task-based Asynchronous Pattern (TAP). Link to text -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async