# New python "async" and "await" for actual parallelization?

Tags: python, asynchronous, parallel-processing, python-3.5

The latest version of [Python, 3.5](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-350/), implements the `async` and `await` keywords for asynchronous coroutines. I am beginning to get my head around them, and I understand that there is a [distinction between concurrency and parallelism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050222/concurrency-vs-parallelism-what-is-the-difference). Nonetheless, they are related and very often you can do concurrent tasks in parallel.

Hence, I am wondering: is there any way to use the new  `async` and `await` features to do actual parallelism?

Answer (score 3):

Currently in python, parallel processing needs to be done using the `multiprocessing` module, forking your process into multiple ones. This is because python has [THE GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock), a 'feature' that prevents any one python interpreter from having multiple threads running in parallel. The new `async` / `await` are going to help people make asynchronous (concurrent) programs easier, but I don't think that they're going to help us with actual parallel computing.