# What problems Hyperthreading can solve?

Tags: operating-system, hyperthreading

Sorry for being stupid but recently I stamped upon Hyperthreading and I was amazed how epic and awesome it is but I was wondering what problems it can fix.

Comment: In a nutshell ALU and FPU starvation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So hyperthreading refers to having more virtual **CPU** to one real **CPU**. Because we only have one real **CPU** we can only execute one instruction at a time (so no parallelism). So, what really happens is that the **CPU** pretends it has more cores and it uses his logic to speed up execution. The virtual **CPUs** can share physical execution resources. Hyperthreading can speedup the execution of a program but it is not as good as having more real **CPUs**.

Check out these answers for more detailed info: [Does a hyperthreading CPU implement parallelism or just concurrency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33358477/does-a-hyperthreading-cpu-implement-parallelism-or-just-concurrency/33358705)