# springboot/hibernate queries result takes too much time

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

I am developing a Springboot application, and my requirements are the following:

I have 8 sql queries, that I have to run in parallel and that return a single result. 
My entities using this sql requests are:

```java
@SqlResultSetMapping(name = "bud01Mapping", classes = {
        @ConstructorResult(targetClass = Bud01Entity.class, columns = {
                @ColumnResult(name = "MNTBUDGETMB", type = Double.class),

        }
        ) })

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Bud01Entity {

    @Id
    private Double mntBudgetMB;

}
```

To avoid duplication in my post, please consider: Bud01Entity, Bud02Entity ... until Bud08Entity.

My queries are implemented in an hbm.xml file `Bud01Entity.hbm.xml` as follow:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entity-mappings
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm_2_0.xsd"
        version="2.0">
    <entity
            class="budget.Bud01Entity"
            name="Bud01Entity">

        <named-native-query
                name="Bud01Entity.findBud01"
                result-set-mapping="bud01Mapping">
            <query>
                SELECT
                SUM(CASE WHEN budget.sens='C' THEN -1 * budget.mnt_budget ELSE budget.mnt_budget END) AS mntBudgetProduction,
                ent.code as codService
                FROM si.t_sb_budget budget
                JOIN si.t_sb_rubrique_budget rub ON rub.pk_id_rubrique_budget = budget.fk_id_rubrique_budget
                JOIN si.t_ga_activite act ON act.pk_id_activite = budget.fk_id_activite
                JOIN si.t_rd_service serv ON act.fk_id_service = serv.pk_id
                JOIN si.t_rd_entite ent ON ent.pk_id = serv.pk_id
                JOIN si.t_sb_type_budget typ_bud ON typ_bud.pk_id_type_budget=budget.fk_id_type_budget
                WHERE budget.exercice       = :codAnnee
                AND ent.code                = :codService
                AND typ_bud.pk_id_type_budget = 6
                GROUP BY
                ent.code
            </query>
        </named-native-query>

    </entity>
</entity-mappings>
```

As for the first one, to avoid duplication in my post, please consider: Bud01Entity.hbm.xml, Bud02Entity.hbm.xml ... Bud08Entity.hbm.xml.

My service is implemented as follow:

```java
@Async
@Slf4j
@Service
public class Bud01Service {

    @Autowired
    private Bud01Repository bud01Repository;

    public CompletableFuture<List<Bud01Entity>> findBud(String codService, String codAnnee) {
        log.info("Running findBud for service {} and annee {}", codService, codAnnee);
        List<Bud01Entity> data = bud01Repository.findBud01(codService, codAnnee);
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(data);
    }
}
```

Same as the other, same logic for Bud02Service, ...Bud08Service.

My repository interface is as follow:

```java
@Repository
public interface Bud01Repository extends JpaRepository<Bud01Entity, Double> {
    List<Bud01Entity> findBud01(@Param("codService") String codService, @Param("codAnnee") String codAnnee);
}
```

Each of this 8 results represent attributes of BudAllEntity:

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class BudAllEntity {

    private Double mntBudgetProduction;
    private Double mntBudgetMB;
    private Double mntBudgetRegul;
    private Double mntBudgetFraisGenAct;
    private Double mntBudgetFraisGenSer;
    private Double mntBudgetFraisGenReg;
    private Double mntBudgetFraisGenSie;
    private Double mntBudgetFraisFin;

}
```

And my aggregation endpoint:

```java
@Slf4j
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/AggBud")
public class BudAggEndpoint {

    @Autowired
    private Bud01Service bud01Service;

    @Autowired
    private Bud02Service bud02Service;

    @Autowired
    private Bud03Service bud03Service;

    @Autowired
    private Bud04Service bud04Service;

    @Autowired
    private Bud05Service bud05Service;

    @Autowired
    private Bud06Service bud06Service;

    @Autowired
    private Bud07Service bud07Service;

    @Autowired
    private Bud08Service bud08Service;

    @GetMapping(value = "details", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
    public Page<BudAllEntity> findBudClient(@RequestParam(value = "codService") String codService,
                                            @RequestParam(value = "codAnnee") String codAnnee,
                                            @RequestParam(required = false) Pageable pageRequest) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

        CompletableFuture<List<Bud01Entity>> att1 = bud01Service.findBud(codService, codAnnee);
        CompletableFuture<List<Bud02Entity>> att2 = bud02Service.findBud(codService, codAnnee);
        CompletableFuture<List<Bud03Entity>> att3 = bud03Service.findBud(codService, codAnnee);
        CompletableFuture<List<Bud04Entity>> att4 = bud04Service.findBud(codService, codAnnee);
        CompletableFuture<List<Bud05Entity>> att5 = bud05Service.findBud(codService, codAnnee);
        CompletableFuture<List<Bud06Entity>> att6 = bud06Service.findBud(codService, codAnnee);
        CompletableFuture<List<Bud07Entity>> att7 = bud07Service.findBud(codService, codAnnee);
        CompletableFuture<List<Bud08Entity>> att8 = bud08Service.findBud(codService, codAnnee);

        CompletableFuture.allOf(att1, att2, att3, att4, att5, att6, att7, att8);

        log.info("Retrieve Budgets");

        List<BudAllEntity> finalResult = new ArrayList<BudAllEntity>();
        BudAllEntity result = new BudAllEntity();
        try{
            result.setMntBudgetProduction(att1.get().get(0).getMntBudgetProduction());
            result.setMntBudgetMB(att2.get().get(0).getMntBudgetMB());
            result.setMntBudgetRegul(att3.get().get(0).getMntBudgetRegul());
            result.setMntBudgetFraisGenAct(att4.get().get(0).getMntBudgetFraisGenAct());
            result.setMntBudgetFraisGenReg(att5.get().get(0).getMntBudgetFraisGenSer());
            result.setMntBudgetFraisGenSer(att6.get().get(0).getMntBudgetFraisGenReg());
            result.setMntBudgetFraisGenSie(att7.get().get(0).getMntBudgetFraisGenSie());
            result.setMntBudgetFraisFin(att8.get().get(0).getMntBudgetFraisFin());
        } catch (Exception e){
            log.error(e.getMessage(),e);
        }


        finalResult.add(result);
        Pageable page = Optional.ofNullable(pageRequest).orElse(PageRequest.of(0, 20));
        return new ResponsePage<>(finalResult, page, finalResult.size());
    }
}
```

I have added `@EnableAsync` annotation in my main class.

Is there a way to make this code more performant, more simple ?

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach you are following looks pretty good, but there are some minute mistakes you need to take care

## [@Async Annotation](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-async) It should be annotated on method not class

- it must be applied to public methods only
- self-invocation – calling the async method from within the same class – won't work

> The reasons are simple – the method needs to be public so that it can be proxied. And self-invocation doesn't work because it bypasses the proxy and calls the underlying method directly.

## Override the Executor :

> By default, Spring uses a SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor to actually run these methods asynchronously.

Override the default executor

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class SpringAsyncConfig {
 
    @Bean(name = "threadPoolTaskExecutor")
     public Executor threadPoolTaskExecutor() {
     ThreadPoolTaskExecutor pool = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
     pool.setMaxPoolSize(10);
     return pool;
     }
 }
```

Then the executor name should be provided as an attribute in @Async:

```
@Async("threadPoolTaskExecutor")
public void asyncMethodWithConfiguredExecutor() {
    System.out.println("Execute method with configured executor - "
      + Thread.currentThread().getName());
}
```

**Note :** Make sure you create executor thread pool with N of threads that matches to cpu resources [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34689857/9959152)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, could you please explain the added value of the Executor and how to define number of threads ?

Comment: updated the answer, there are so many other properties also please take a look at doc https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.html @DrissNejjar

Comment: So I have tried your solution, and it's better, bu tI think that I have to improve my sql requests. Do you know if there is a way to know if my performance issues are coming from springboot or from my database ? may be you know a tip ? using logging or something like this ?

Comment: On the other hand, since I only have 8 requests, do I take advantages of threadPoolExecutor ? I don't find valuable parameters that I can modify.

Comment: If your queries are taking longer then you should something like `Indexes` on table, try to see the explain plan on query @DrissNejjar