# How do threads of java compare to physical processor's threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, processor

For example, I have 4 core processor with 8 threads. I pretty sure, that this amount of threads does not directly relate on amount of java's threads.

Comment: Checkout this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34689709/java-threads-and-number-of-cores) which has extensively answered your question.

Comment: unfortunately, hardware and software engineers use terms "thread" and "processor" in different ways. Processor threads are processors from software point of view.

Answer (score 6):

As per my understanding you are talking about **4 actual cores** and **2 Hyper-thread per core** which means technically **8 virtual core (vCpu)**. Which means **8 threads** can execute parallel without any context switch (Lets do not consider the complications of Hyper-threads here)

Java threads are **one to one mapped** with the **OS threads** which is **NOT** one to one mapped with **hardware threads**. Which means for `thread allocation` and `context switch`, Java depends on the underlying `OS` on which `JVM` is running. OS can create as many threads it wants, which can run on any of the available `vCPUs` on the processor. As OS threads keep on increasing, there will be more context switches and performance may get affected if threads are `NOT` doing `IO bound` work.