# How does a python thread work?

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing

I was wondering if python threads run concurrently or in parallel?

For example, if I have two tasks and run them inside two threads will they be running simultaneously or will they be scheduled to run concurrently?

I'm aware of **GIL** and that the threads are using just one CPU core.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a complicated question with a lot of explication needed. I'm going to stick with CPython simply because it's the most widely used and what I have experience with.

- A Python thread is a *system* thread that requires the Python interpreter natively to execute its contents into bytecode at runtime. The GIL is an interpreter-specific (in this case, CPython) lock that forces each thread to *acquire* a lock on the interpreter, preventing two threads from running at the same time no matter what core they're on.
- *No* CPU core can run more than one thread at a time. You *need* multiple cores to even talk sensibly about parallelism. Concurrency is not the same as parallelism - the former implies operations between two threads can be interleaved before either are finished but where neither thread need not start at the same time, while the latter implies operations that can be *started* at the same time. If that confuses you, better descriptions about the difference are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050222/concurrency-vs-parallelism-what-is-the-difference).
- There are ways to introduce concurrency in a single-core CPU - namely, have threads that suspend (put themselves to sleep) and resume when needed - but there is *no* way to introduce parallelism with a single core.

Because of these facts, as a consequence, it depends.

- System threads are inherently designed to be concurrent - there wouldn't be much point in having an operating system otherwise. Whether or not they are actually executed this way depends on the task: is there an atomic lock somewhere? (As we shall see, there is!)
- Threads that execute CPU-bound computations - where there is a lot of code being executed, and concurrently the interpreter is dynamically invoked for each line - obtain a lock on the GIL that prevents other threads from executing the same. So, in *that* circumstance, only one thread works at a time across all cores, because no other thread can acquire the interpreter.

  That being said, threads *don't* need to keep the GIL until they are finished, instead acquiring and releasing the lock as/when needed. It is possible for two threads to interleave their operations, because the GIL could be released at the end of a code block, grabbed by the other thread, released at the end of *that* code block, and so on. They won't run in *parallel* - but they can certainly be run concurrently.
- I/O bound threads, on the other hand, spend a large amount of their time simply waiting for requests to complete. These threads don't acquire the GIL - why would they, when there's nothing to interpret? - so certainly you can have multiple I/O-waiting threads run in parallel, one core per thread. The minute code needs to be compiled to bytecode, however, (maybe you need to handle your request?) up goes the GIL again.
- Processes in Python survive the GIL, because they're a collection of resources bundled with threads. Each process has its *own* interpreter, and therefore each *thread* in a process only has to compete with its own immediate process siblings for the GIL. That is why process-based parallelism is the recommended way to go in Python, even though it consumes more resources overall.

### The Upshot

So two tasks in two threads *could* run in **parallel** provided they don't need access to the CPython interpreter. This could happen if they are waiting for I/O requests or are making use of a suitable other language (say, C) extension that doesn't require the Python interpreter, using a foreign function interface.

All threads can run *concurrently* in the sense of interleaved atomic operations. Exactly how *atomic* these interleavings can be - is the GIL released after a code block? After every line? - depends on the task and the thread. Python threads don't have to execute serially - one thread finishes, and then the other starts - so there is concurrency in that sense.

Answer (score 1):

In CPython, the threads are real OS threads, and are scheduled to run concurrently by the operating system. However, as you noted the GIL means that only one thread will be executing instructions at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Let me explain what all that means. Threads run inside the same virtual machine, and hence run on the same physical machine. Processes can run on the same physical machine or in another physical machine. If you architect your application around threads, you’ve done nothing to access multiple machines. So, you can scale to as many cores are on the single machine (which will be quite a few over time), but to really reach web scales, you’ll need to solve the multiple machine problem anyway.