# Are gunicorns threads real?

Tags: python, gunicorn

Im trying to develop a flask application with gunicorn, since gunicorn is implemented in python (i checked github). My question are gunicorn's threads or under GIL ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The threads are actually always real. The issue, as you point out, is that if there is a global interpreter lock (GIL) in place, the interpreter gets locked *while it's interpreting Python*, preventing threads from working simultaneously. Since Gunicorn is written in Python, it's bound by the laws of whatever Python implementation you're using, which may have a GIL.

Both CPython and PyPy have a GIL, but that doesn't mean threading is useless. For as long as whats being executed doesn't require interpretation (e.g. I/O operations), multiple threads can be used without locking.

See the lovely answer on [how a Python thread work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36820151/how-does-a-python-thread-work) for details.