# Number of max_workers when using ThreadPoolExecutor from concurrent.futures?

Tags: python, python-3.x, concurrent.futures

What are the factors to consider when deciding what to set max_workers to in ThreadPoolExecutor from concurrent.futures?

As long as you can expect Python 3.5+ to be available, is there any reason not to set max_workers to None which will then "default to the number of processors on the machine, multiplied by 5" as described in the docs here?
https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor

Answer (score 21):

I don't think this question can be so generically solved; it will depend on each case.

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40505434/5802289):

> The more threads you use, the higher concurrency you'll achieve (up to
>   a point), but the less CPU cycles you'll get (as there will be context
>   switches). You have to instrument your application under typical
>   workloads to see what works best for you. There is no universally
>   optimal solution for this.

Comment: Would appreciate comments saying why it is wrong, instead of just getting a minus vote.. :(

Comment: Another point to consider depending on what you run in parallel is the memory footprint.