# How to use asyncio with existing blocking library?

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, python-3.5, python-asyncio

I have a few blocking functions `foo`, `bar` and I can't change those (Some internal library I don't control. Talks to one or more network services). How do I use it as async? E.g. I want to do the following:

```
results = []
for inp in inps:
    val = foo(inp)
    result = bar(val)
    results.append(result)
```

This will be inefficient as I can call `foo` for the second input while I am waiting for the first and same for `bar`. How do I wrap them such that they are usable with asyncio (i.e new `async`, `await` syntax)?

Lets assume the functions are re-entrant. i.e it is fine to call `foo` again when already a previous `foo` is processing.

---

**Update**

Extending answer with reusable decorator. Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53719009/) for example.

```
def run_in_executor(f):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
        return loop.run_in_executor(None, functools.partial(f, *args, **kwargs))

    return inner
```

Comment: stackoverflow documentation has been shutdown

Answer (score 65, accepted):

There are (sort of) two questions here:

1. how can I run blocking code asynchronously within a coroutine
2. how can I run multiple async tasks at the "same" time (as an aside: asyncio is single-threaded, so it is [concurrent, but not *truly* parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050222/what-is-the-difference-between-concurrency-and-parallelism)).

Concurrent tasks can be created using the high-level [`asyncio.create_task`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.create_task) or the low-level [`asyncio.ensure_future`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-future.html#asyncio.ensure_future). Starting with 3.11, they can also be created through [asyncio task groups](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/asyncio-task.html#task-groups), as pioneered by the Trio library (the creator of Trio has an excellent blog post on the subject [here](https://vorpus.org/blog/notes-on-structured-concurrency-or-go-statement-considered-harmful/)).

To run synchronous code, you will need to [run the blocking code in an executor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#executing-code-in-thread-or-process-pools). Example:

```
import concurrent.futures
import asyncio
import time

def blocking(delay):
    time.sleep(delay)
    print('Completed.')


async def non_blocking(executor):
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    # Run three of the blocking tasks concurrently. asyncio.wait will
    # automatically wrap these in Tasks. If you want explicit access
    # to the tasks themselves, use asyncio.ensure_future, or add a
    # "done, pending = asyncio.wait..." assignment
    await asyncio.wait(
        fs={
            # Returns after delay=12 seconds
            loop.run_in_executor(executor, blocking, 12),
            
            # Returns after delay=14 seconds
            loop.run_in_executor(executor, blocking, 14),
            
            # Returns after delay=16 seconds
            loop.run_in_executor(executor, blocking, 16)
        },
        return_when=asyncio.ALL_COMPLETED
    )

executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5)
asyncio.run(non_blocking(executor))
```

If you want to schedule these tasks using a for loop (as in your example), you have several different strategies, but the underlying approach is to *schedule* the tasks using the for loop (or list comprehension, etc),  await them with asyncio.wait, and *then* retrieve the results. Example:

```
done, pending = await asyncio.wait(
    fs=[loop.run_in_executor(executor, blocking_foo, *args) for args in inps],
    return_when=asyncio.ALL_COMPLETED
)

# Note that any errors raise during the above will be raised here; to
# handle errors you will need to call task.exception() and check if it
# is not None before calling task.result()
results = [task.result() for task in done]
```

Comment: asyncio.ensure_future is not mandatory in this case as [asyncio.wait](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait) will already wrap coroutines in Tasks.

Comment: Good tip! Though for a less-toy example, ensure_future might still be useful for ex. cancellation (irrespective of pending, complete).

Comment: The anchor in the link to "run the blocking code in an executor" is out of date -- [this one](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#executing-code-in-thread-or-process-pools) seem to be the latest at this point.

Comment: So this will not really be in parallel ? How can I turn into really parallel code? why asyncio.sleep(). is truly parallel ?

Comment: @user1628688 it depends if you *really* mean parallel, or if you actually mean *concurrent*. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050222/what-is-the-difference-between-concurrency-and-parallelism) for an explanation of the difference. (side note, I had to correct my original answer, as I had them reversed there).

Most cpython code cannot be parallel, and must be only concurrent, because of the GIL. This is a language runtime limitation; it's not something you can avoid without getting low-level. Furthermore, async/await code is (AFAIK) inherently single-threaded anyways.

Comment: See my answer or how you can now also just use `asyncio.to_thread` to asynchronously run function in a separate thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73706858/2340939

Answer (score 37):

Extending the accepted answer to actually solve the problem in question.

Note: Requires python 3.7+

```
import functools

from urllib.request import urlopen
import asyncio


def legacy_blocking_function():  # You cannot change this function
    r = urlopen("https://example.com")
    return r.read().decode()


def run_in_executor(f):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
        return loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda: f(*args, **kwargs))

    return inner


@run_in_executor
def foo(arg):  # Your wrapper for async use
    resp = legacy_blocking_function()
    return f"{arg}{len(resp)}"


@run_in_executor
def bar(arg):  # Another wrapper
    resp = legacy_blocking_function()
    return f"{len(resp)}{arg}"


async def process_input(inp):  # Modern async function (coroutine)
    res = await foo(inp)
    res = f"XXX{res}XXX"
    return await bar(res)


async def main():
    inputs = ["one", "two", "three"]
    input_tasks = [asyncio.create_task(process_input(inp)) for inp in inputs]
    print([await t for t in asyncio.as_completed(input_tasks)])
    # This doesn't work as expected :(
    # print([await t for t in asyncio.as_completed([process_input(inp) for inp in input_tasks])])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

---

Click [here](https://github.com/balkierode/assortedscripts/blob/master/python/blockex.py) for up to date version of this example and to send pull requests.

Comment: I ran across this one when was looking for an answer. This example is very informative, but not fully correct. Actual wrapper function should contain `async`/`await` keywords.

```def run_in_executor(f):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    async def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
        return await loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda: f(*args, **kwargs))
    return inner```

Answer (score 12):

Now you can also just use `asyncio.to_thread` to asynchronously run function in a separate thread.

```
import asyncio
import time

def blocking():
    print("Started!")
    time.sleep(5)
    print("Finished!")

async def non_blocking():
    print("Started!")
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    print("Finished!")

async def main():
    print("Blocking function:")
    start_time = time.time()
    await asyncio.gather(*(asyncio.to_thread(blocking) for i in range(5)))
    print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))

    print("Non-blocking function:")
    start_time = time.time()
    await asyncio.gather(*(non_blocking() for i in range(5)))
    print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))

asyncio.run(main())
```

Output:

```
Blocking function:
Started!
Started!
Started!
Started!
Started!
Finished!
Finished!
Finished!
Finished!
Finished!
--- 5.018239736557007 seconds ---
Non-blocking function:
Started!
Started!
Started!
Started!
Started!
Finished!
Finished!
Finished!
Finished!
Finished!
--- 5.005802392959595 seconds ---
```

Documentation: https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.to_thread

Comment: Note: This function is available from python [3.9](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.to_thread)

Comment: How do I use a semaphore with this ?

Answer (score 5):

```
import asyncio
from time import sleep
import logging

logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.DEBUG, format="%(asctime)s %(thread)s %(funcName)s %(message)s")


def long_task(t):
    """Simulate long IO bound task."""
    logging.info("2. t: %s", t)
    sleep(t)
    logging.info("4. t: %s", t)
    return t ** 2


async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    inputs = range(1, 5)
    logging.info("1.")
    futures = [loop.run_in_executor(None, long_task, i) for i in inputs]
    logging.info("3.")
    results = await asyncio.gather(*futures)
    logging.info("5.")
    for (i, result) in zip(inputs, results):
        logging.info("6. Result: %s, %s", i, result)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Output:

```
2020-03-18 17:13:07,523 23964 main 1.
2020-03-18 17:13:07,524 5008 long_task 2. t: 1
2020-03-18 17:13:07,525 21232 long_task 2. t: 2
2020-03-18 17:13:07,525 22048 long_task 2. t: 3
2020-03-18 17:13:07,526 25588 long_task 2. t: 4
2020-03-18 17:13:07,526 23964 main 3.
2020-03-18 17:13:08,526 5008 long_task 4. t: 1
2020-03-18 17:13:09,526 21232 long_task 4. t: 2
2020-03-18 17:13:10,527 22048 long_task 4. t: 3
2020-03-18 17:13:11,527 25588 long_task 4. t: 4
2020-03-18 17:13:11,527 23964 main 5.
2020-03-18 17:13:11,528 23964 main 6. Result: 1, 1
2020-03-18 17:13:11,528 23964 main 6. Result: 2, 4
2020-03-18 17:13:11,529 23964 main 6. Result: 3, 9
2020-03-18 17:13:11,529 23964 main 6. Result: 4, 16
```