# When running boto3 in muti-threaded code, a botocore.vendored.six.moves has not attribute error is raised

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

Because calls to AWS REST API can be long-running (especially when dealing with CloudFormation calls) I have used `asyncio` to parallelize calls, with an `executor` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41063331/how-to-use-asyncio-with-existing-blocking-library) for more info).

However, when some of the calls failed (or even without failures) I get this error:

`[ERROR] module 'botocore.vendored.six.moves' has no attribute 'configparser'`

without any further indication (e.g., a stacktrace) to figure out what the root cause is.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [this issue](https://github.com/boto/botocore/issues/1227), the issue appears to be with the version of `six` that `botocore` embeds in an earlier version.

I added the following to my `requirements.txt`:

```
botocore==1.7.22
```

and then run:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

and the error went away.