# asyncio.sleep() vs time.sleep()

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, python-asyncio, sleep

When I go to the `asyncio` page, the first example is a hello world program. When I run it on python `3.73`, I can't see any different from the normal one. **can anyone tell me the difference and give a non-trivial example?**

```
In [1]: import asyncio
   ...:
   ...: async def main():
   ...:     print('Hello ...')
   ...:     await asyncio.sleep(5)
   ...:     print('... World!')
   ...:
   ...: # Python 3.7+
   ...: asyncio.run(main())
Hello ...
... World!

In [2]:

In [2]: import time
   ...:
   ...: def main():
   ...:     print('Hello ...')
   ...:     time.sleep(5)
   ...:     print('... World!')
   ...:
   ...: # Python 3.7+
   ...: main()
Hello ...
... World!
```

I intentionally increase the time from 1s to 5s, hope to see something special but I didn't.

Comment: there are many resources on this out there... this is one: https://realpython.com/async-io-python/

Comment: Did you expect something different?

Comment: @KennyOstrom Yes, I think an example should be a simplest nontrivial one

Comment: About `asyncio.sleep` accuracy https://stackoverflow.com/a/65727201/13782669

Comment: There is no Python 3.73 yet; did you mean 3.7.3?

Answer (score 232, accepted):

You aren't seeing anything special because there's nothing much asynchronous work in your code. However, the main difference is that `time.sleep(5)` is blocking, and `asyncio.sleep(5)` is non-blocking.

When `time.sleep(5)` is called, it will block the entire execution of the script and it will be put on hold, just frozen, doing nothing. But when you call `await asyncio.sleep(5)`, it will ask the event loop to run something else while your await statement finishes its execution.

Here's an improved example.

```
import asyncio

async def hello():
    print('Hello ...')
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print('... World!')

async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(hello(), hello())

asyncio.run(main())
```

Will output:

```
~$ python3.7 async.py
Hello ...
Hello ...
... World!
... World!
```

You can see that `await asyncio.sleep(1)` is not blocking the execution of the script.

In contrast, replacing the line `await asyncio.sleep(1)` with `time.sleep(1)`, the output will be

```
Hello ...
... World!
Hello ...
... World!
```

because `time.sleep` is blocking and the first call of `hello()` has to finish first before the second call of `hello()` starts running.

Comment: some explanation from me which helped me to understand sync vs. async sleep - if you need pause an entire script (supposed to work concurrently) execution, it is sleep. If you need to pause single coroutine, it is asyncio.sleep

Comment: Correction: You wrote "When time.sleep(5) is called, it will block the entire execution of the script ". This is true only for single threaded script. But for the general case this is incorrect. time.sleep(5) blocks only the current thread.

Comment: @eyalzba yeah, it makes sense. Thank you for adding this comment :)

Comment: This should be the official "hello world" example.

Comment: Thanks to stackoverflow.com and programmers like you, so many "holes" in standard PY documentation are covered. (One couldn't  dig this out from https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html!)

Comment: Does anyone know if this experiences drift (topic pointed out throughout this stack overflow post regarding looping a function periodically)? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/474528/what-is-the-best-way-to-repeatedly-execute-a-function-every-x-seconds

Comment: Note that all standard library functions that make a syscall do release the GIL (https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-GIL), including the `time.sleep` function. Hence you can run the blocking function `time.sleep` function asynchronously, e.g. via `asyncio.to_thread`. See examples:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67122173/2340939
https://stackoverflow.com/a/73706858/2340939

Answer (score 12):

With [**time.sleep(1)**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html?highlight=sleep#time.sleep) below, first, **`test1()`** is run every one second, then **`test2()`** is run every one second:

```py
import asyncio
import time

async def test1():
    for _ in range(0, 3):
        print('Test1')
        time.sleep(1) # Here
        
async def test2():
    for _ in range(0, 3):
        print('Test2')
        time.sleep(1) # Here
    
async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(test1(), test2()) # Here

asyncio.run(main())
```

So, **6 seconds** are taken to run **`test1()`** and **`test2()`** in total:

```
Test1 # 1 second
Test1 # 2 seconds
Test1 # 3 seconds
Test2 # 4 seconds
Test2 # 5 seconds
Test2 # 6 seconds
```

With [**asyncio.sleep(1)**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.sleep) below, **`test1()`** and **`test2()`** are run every one second alternately:

```py
import asyncio

async def test1():
    for _ in range(0, 3):
        print('Test1')
        await asyncio.sleep(1) # Here
        
async def test2():
    for _ in range(0, 3):
        print('Test2')
        await asyncio.sleep(1) # Here
    
async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(test1(), test2()) # Here

asyncio.run(main())
```

So, only **3 seconds** are taken to run **`test1()`** and **`test2()`** in total:

```
Test1 # 1 second
Test2 # 1 second
Test1 # 2 seconds
Test2 # 2 seconds
Test1 # 3 seconds
Test2 # 3 seconds
```

And, with [**time.sleep(0)**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html?highlight=sleep#time.sleep) below, first, **`test1()`** is run at once, then **`test2()`** is run at once:

```py
import asyncio
import time

async def test1():
    for _ in range(0, 3):
        print('Test1')
        time.sleep(0) # Here
        
async def test2():
    for _ in range(0, 3):
        print('Test2')
        time.sleep(0) # Here
    
async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(test1(), test2()) # Here

asyncio.run(main())
```

So, **0 second** is taken to run **`test1()`** and **`test2()`** in total:

```
Test1 # 0 second
Test1 # 0 second
Test1 # 0 second
Test2 # 0 second
Test2 # 0 second
Test2 # 0 second
```

And, with [**asyncio.sleep(0)**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.sleep) below, **`test1()`** and **`test2()`** are run at once alternately:

```py
import asyncio

async def test1():
    for _ in range(0, 3):
        print('Test1')
        await asyncio.sleep(0) # Here
        
async def test2():
    for _ in range(0, 3):
        print('Test2')
        await asyncio.sleep(0) # Here
    
async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(test1(), test2()) # Here

asyncio.run(main())
```

So, only **0 second** is taken to run **`test1()`** and **`test2()`** in total:

```
Test1 # 0 second
Test2 # 0 second
Test1 # 0 second
Test2 # 0 second
Test1 # 0 second
Test2 # 0 second
```

Lastly, without [**time.sleep()**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html?highlight=sleep#time.sleep) or [**asyncio.sleep()**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.sleep) below, first, **`test1()`** is run at once, then **`test2()`** is run at once:

```py
import asyncio

async def test1():
    for _ in range(0, 3):
        print('Test1')
        
async def test2():
    for _ in range(0, 3):
        print('Test2')
    
async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(test1(), test2()) # Here

asyncio.run(main())
```

So, **0 second** is taken to run **`test1()`** and **`test2()`** in total:

```
Test1 # 0 second
Test1 # 0 second
Test1 # 0 second
Test2 # 0 second
Test2 # 0 second
Test2 # 0 second
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference is the unit of concurrency that is blocked: threads vs coroutines (asyncio tasks).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35573888)