# Executing a function after a certain period of time

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I am building a discord bot with discordpy and I want a function to be executed every ten minutes (for a mini game) but if I use `time.sleep` the entire program will freeze and wait for that time, rendering my bot completely useless because of the fact that `time.sleep` stops the program from executing. Also discordpy works with async functions and events so trying to find a place to put a while loop is very difficult. Is there a module that I can use to execute a function every ten minutes without stopping the flow of my bot?

edit:
with discordpy, you define all of your async functions so:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    # Code
```

And than at the end of the file you write:
`client.run()`
What I am saying is, I cant use an infinite while loop because of the fact that I need to reach that line, without that line the bot will be useless, So what my question is, can I "attach" a timer to my script so that every ten minutes I can execute a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you use scheduling for this

```
import sched, time
sch = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
def run_sch(do): 
   print("running at 10 mins")
   # do your stuff
   sch.enter(600, 1, run_sch, (do,))

sch.enter(600, 1, run_sch, (s,))
sch.run()
```

or you can try threading for running that specific function for every 10 mins

```
import threading

def hello_world():
    while True:
       print("Hello, World!")
       time.sleep(600)
t1 = threading.Thread(target=hello_world)
t1.start()
while True:
   print('in loop')
   time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: I tried this one and I believe program execution also stops. I may just be doing it wrong.

Comment: try second one which will not stop your execution of other task..all function in thread for which you want run in parallel

Comment: This one seems like itll work, but with threading does it matter if my program is force shut down. (I think its called keyboard interrupting)

Comment: This is not a proper solution. Discord.py uses `asyncio` so the right way to do it would be awaiting for `asyncio.sleep` Please refer to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Tell me what you think about this. If it does not work with your code then I can adjust it:

```
import time
starttime=time.time()
def thing():
  print('hi')
while True:
  thing()
  time.sleep(60.0 - ((time.time() - starttime) % 60.0))
```

It's in a while loop so I don't know how well that will work with your code but since it is a bot that runs multiple times, it might work. Of course if you want it to run only 5 times for example you can just say for i in range(5):
Hope this helps!

Comment: There is no place to put this loop because of the fact that with discordpy, the bot executes on a loop through a function. For example you just call `client.run()` and it goes into an infinite while so, I have not found a place to put this where its effective.

Comment: Now this does execute the function every so often but this does not allow for the execution of the bot.

Comment: Well if your function runs on a loop, is it possible to take it out?. Do you think you can edit your question and put our code in so it is easier to help you out. Because I might be able to shove it in somewhere.

Comment: In discordpy you type out all of your async functions and then at the bottom you type `client.run()` which is an infinite loop, like the only way to get out of it is by killing the program. So there is no loop that I can add code to that I can see.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this,

```
import schedule

def worker():
    print("Executing...")

schedule.every(10).minutes.do(worker)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Also, there are different packages we can use to achieve this feature.

```
import sched
sched.scheduler(params)
```

```
Threading along with sleep.
Use of Twisted package etc..
```

Comment: I tried to replicate this but because of the infinite while loop at the bottom of your code, program execution never reaches `client.run()` for example. In discordpy you set up all of your async functions, then at the bottom of the script you type `client.run()` and that function is the infinite loop that I need to be in, but because this uses one, I never reach it.

Answer (score 0):

Discord.py is build with python asyncio module. To sleep the current task in asyncio, you need to await on `asyncio.sleep()` Note that this will not block your thread or the event loop and is exactly what you should use.

```py
import asyncio #Top of your file
...

await asyncio.sleep(10) #Doesn't blocks the rest of the program!
```

Creating a thread as mentioned in the answer by NAGA RAJ S is not recommended in asynchronous programs and is a waste of resource.

More about `asyncio.sleep` v/s `time.sleep`: [Python 3.7 - asyncio.sleep() and time.sleep()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56729764/python-3-7-asyncio-sleep-and-time-sleep)