# Set a cooldown in commands

Tags: discord.py

I wanted to set a cooldown for my bot in discord.py, I tried to do this with `time.sleep(30)`, but it didn't work because it stops the full bot, but I need that you can do other commands in the time. Please in content.split and not discord ext. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to use a decorator on your command.
The decorator for a cooldown is `@commands.cooldown`

```
@bot.command()
@commands.cooldown(x, y, commands.BucketType.z)
#your code here
...
```

x is how many times a command can be used in a given timeframe

y is that timeframe (in seconds)

z is who this applies to (a user, a channel, a server, or even global(default))

So: `...cooldown(2, 10, commands.BucketType.user)` will allow every user to use the command 2 times within 10 seconds.

Good luck!

You can read up on it here: [Discord.py commands.cooldown](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=commands%20cooldown#discord.ext.commands.cooldown)

As a sidenote: `time.sleep()` is something you can use to "pause" the bot within a command

```
print("hi")
time.sleep(30)
print("there")
```

This will put a delay between the two messages, instead of having them be printed immediately, one after the other. You should test this out in!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `asyncio.sleep()` for waiting inside the function, ex. inside `on_ready()` event or `@commands.cooldown` decorator (designed only for [commands](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?#commands)):

### asyncio.sleep()

```py
import asyncio 

asyncio.sleep(seconds)
```

`Asyncio.sleep` works like `time.sleep`, but it doesn't block the entire code. It stops only one event. You can read more about the difference between `time.sleep` and `asyncio.sleep` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56729764/python-3-7-asyncio-sleep-and-time-sleep).

---

### @commands.cooldown()

```py
@client.command()
@commands.cooldown(rate, per, type)
async def example(ctx):
...
```

- **rate -** The number of times a command can be used before triggering a cooldown.
- **per -** The number of seconds to wait for a cooldown when it’s been triggered.
- **type -** The type of cooldown (cooldown that blocks **only one user** would be `commands.BucketType.user`. [Check all types and choose one that suits your needs.](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?%20cooldown#discord.ext.commands.BucketType)

Answer (score 0):

this is because time.sleep is blocking, you can use

```py
@commands.cooldown(1, 5, commands.BucketType.user)
```