# python: asyncio.wait_for doesn't stop after given timeout

Tags: python, python-asyncio

In the following example, I expect that `f1()` and `f2()` can stop after `2s`. However, I can run `f1()` in `3s`.

[asyncio.wait_for](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait_for)

```py
import asyncio
import time


async def f1():
    print("start sleep")
    time.sleep(3) # simulate CPU intensive part
    print("end sleep")

    print("start asyncio.sleep")
    await asyncio.sleep(3) # simulate IO intensive part
    print("end asyncio.sleep")


async def f2():
    print("start asyncio.sleep")
    await asyncio.sleep(3) # simulate IO intensive part
    print("end asyncio.sleep")

    print("start sleep")
    time.sleep(3) # simulate CPU intensive part
    print("end sleep")


async def main():
    print("-----f1-----")
    t1 = time.time()
    try:
        await asyncio.wait_for(f1(), timeout=2)
    except:
        pass
    t2 = time.time()
    print(f"f1 cost {(t2 - t1)} s")

    print("-----f2-----")
    t1 = time.time()
    try:
        await asyncio.wait_for(f2(), timeout=2)
    except:
        pass
    t2 = time.time()
    print(f"f2 cost {(t2 - t1)} s")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

the result:

```
-----f1-----
start sleep
end sleep
start asyncio.sleep
f1 cost 3.0005991458892822 s
-----f2-----
start asyncio.sleep
f2 cost 2.0014591217041016 s
```

In my practical usecase, `f1()` has two parts, the first part is CPU intensive and the second part is I/O intensive(only for the 2nd part, I use `async` syntax). I hope the whole `f1()` can stop after fixed time. How to implement this usecase?

Comment: The cause is the order of calls you have defined in `f1` and `f2`. Let us look at the `f2` function, which works as expected. It calls `asyncio.sleep` which has a special implementation to be awaited and does not block I/O while the `time.sleep` does. See the [differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56729764/asyncio-sleep-vs-time-sleep) between `time.sleep` and `asyncio.sleep`.

So the `asyncio.wait_for` works only with I/O bound tasks. Note that calling the `time.sleep` inside of an `async` function does not make it I/O bound.

Comment: @ArtyomVancyan I repost my detailed question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74652884/how-to-run-the-whole-async-function-in-given-timeout