# Python telegram bot v20 run asynchronously

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

```
from telegram import Update
from telegram.ext import ApplicationBuilder, CommandHandler, ContextTypes

import time


async def start(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> None:
    await update.message.reply_text("start")
    time.sleep(10)  # a process that's going to take some time
    await update.message.reply_text("finish")


app = ApplicationBuilder().token("TOKEN HERE").build()

app.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))

app.run_polling()
```

This is the simplest example of the problem i'm currently facing in a project

The bot has to do a process that takes some time to finish

But the bot stops responding to other users during that process

I tried everything

I tried older versions of python telegram bot

I tried using threads (which won't work on async functions) and asyncio (i'm not so familiar with this sorta stuffs but for some reasons still did not respond to other users)

I even tried creating two functions inside the "start" function (one async and one not async) and then running the async function through a thread of the normal function.

```
from telegram import Update

from telegram.ext import ApplicationBuilder, CommandHandler, ContextTypes

import time

import threading

import asyncio

async def start(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> None:

    async def thread1(upd: Update, ctx: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):

        await update.message.reply_text('start')

        time.sleep(10)

        await update.message.reply_text('finish')

    def thread_the_thread(upd: Update, ctx: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):

        loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()

        asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)

        loop.run_until_complete(thread1(upd, ctx))

        loop.close()

    t = threading.Thread(target=thread_the_thread, args=(update, context))

    t.start()

app = ApplicationBuilder().token("TOKEN HERE").build()

app.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))

app.run_polling()
```

But when i used the bot with two different users...

```
telegram.error.NetworkError: Unknown error in HTTP implementation: RuntimeError('<asyncio.locks.Event object at 0x0000022361E0A920 [unset]> is bound to a different event loop')
```

Answer (score 4):

### Documentation

Somehow the related documentation about asynchronous working in PTB (python-telegram-bot) is really hard to google. Hint: use '*concurrency*' keyword.

The answer to your question in official docs is [here](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Concurrency).

### Blocking vs Async

Before jumping to PTB itself, it's worth mentioning that you use **blocking** *time.sleep()* function. In order for it to be asynchronous, you should use the appropriate function: *asyncio.sleep()*.
You could refer to that [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56729764/asyncio-sleep-vs-time-sleep).

### PTB concurrency

As for PTB concurrency: there are 2 ways to make the bot running asynchronously:

**1. block=False**

Use 'block=False' option during adding the handler:

```
app.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start, block=False))
```

Be cautious with that (a quote from PTB docs):

> However, by using block=False in a handler, you can no longer rely on handlers in different groups being called one after the other. Depending on your use case, this can be an issue. Hence, PTB comes with a second option.

**2. concurrent_updates**

Activate concurrent_updates option during building the Application instance:

```
app = ApplicationBuilder().token('TOKEN HERE').concurrent_updates(True).build()
```

### Example

This is my piece of code which running as you expect it to (I'm using Loguru for logging purposes, you could replace it with print() for simplicity):

```
from telegram import Update
from telegram.ext import ApplicationBuilder, CommandHandler, ContextTypes
import asyncio
import random
import sys
from loguru import logger

COUNTER = 0
TOKEN = "TOKEN HERE"
logger.add(sys.stdout, level="TRACE", format="<green>{time}</green> | <blue>{function}</blue> | {message}", serialize=False)


async def logic(num: int) -> int:
    """Some logic to run"""
    delay = random.randint(5, 10)
    logger.trace(f"Logic-{num} to be delayed for {delay} seconds")
    await asyncio.sleep(delay)
    return delay


async def start(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> None:
    msg = 'started'
    logger.trace(msg)

    await context.bot.send_message(
        chat_id=update.message.chat_id,
        text=msg
    )

    global COUNTER
    result = await logic(COUNTER)
    COUNTER +=1
    msg = f"Finished after {result} seconds of working"
    await context.bot.send_message(
        chat_id=update.message.chat_id,
        text=msg
    )
    logger.trace(msg)


def main():
    # option 1: block=False
    # app = ApplicationBuilder().token(TOKEN).build()
    # app.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start, block=False))
   
    # option 2: set concurrent_updates
    app = ApplicationBuilder().token(TOKEN).concurrent_updates(True).build()
    app.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))

    app.run_polling()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Hope that helps.