# Python Asynchronously Calling Synchronous Function

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous, async-await, raspberry-pi3, sensors

I am new to async programming in Python and the internet has not helped me to solve my problem - does anyone of you have a solution?

I have an infinite loop, in which some sensor data is read. However, the sensor reading is quite slow, so I want so await the sensor signals.

My expectation of it looks like this (just the schematics):

```
    import bno055 #sensor library
    import asyncio
    
    aync def read_sensor():
           altitude=bno055.read()
           #..and some other unimportant lines which I hide here
           return altitude


    def main():

       while 1:
          await current_altitude= read_sensor() #??? how can I "await" the sensor signals?
          #....some other lines which I hide here, but they need to run syncronously
          print(current_altitude)

       
      

   main()
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: If `bno055.read` is not asynchronous you need to wrap it somehow in a thread or similar.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use asyncio with existing blocking library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41063331/how-to-use-asyncio-with-existing-blocking-library)

Answer (score 0):

To `await` function doing blocking IO you can run it by means of [run_in_executor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#executing-code-in-thread-or-process-pools)

```
def read_sensor():
    altitude=bno055.read()
    #..and some other unimportant lines which I hide here
    return altitude

loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
altitude = await loop.run_in_executor(None, read_sensor)
```

Comment: Yes, i updated answer, `read_sensor` should not be `async` now

Comment: It returns a syntax error for "await loop.run_in_executor(None, read_sensor)"