# How to make asynchronous work ? I cannot understand the problem

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio

I want to know why this example doesn't work asynchronously ? and what I should change that to make it work. I will really appreciate for any help !

Example 1:

```
import asyncio
import random
import time


nums = list()
[nums.append(x) for x in range(1, 100)]
random_time = random.randint(1, 5)

async def func(num):
    num = num * 2
    time.sleep(random_time)
    print(num)
    return num

async def main():
    tasks = list()
    for num in nums:
        tasks.append(func(num))
    return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
results = loop.run_until_complete(main())
loop.close()
print(f'{len(results)} are asynchronized')
```

Example 2:

[image]

Comment: Your task (`func`) isn't `await`ing anything, it's a normal blocking function. You'll want to use `asyncio.sleep` if you want an asynchronous, non-blocking sleep.

Comment: Would you kindly read [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33357233/when-to-use-and-when-not-to-use-python-3-5-await)? I believe it may help.

Comment: ok, thanks, all ok with first example

Comment: but what about second example ? what's wrong ?

Comment: Second issue is exactly the same thing. Even if you wrap the method in an `async/await` function, that's not changing anything. The actual function itself is blocking. You'd need to find a jira library that works with asyncio and enables you to `await issue.update(...)` for example. You can use executors to run blocking calls in an async fashion: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41063331/476

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code, as they cannot be searched or edited.