# How can I turn a blocking function into a non-blocking function that can run in an infinite loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I have a program that runs synchronously in an infinite loop. And this program needs to use an external library that runs a function that blocks the code. How can I turn this blocking function into a non-blocking function that can run in an infinite loop of the program?

Here is a sample code:

```
import time

SECONDS_TO_WAIT = 3

# imitation of an external library blocking function
def get_data():
    time.sleep(SECONDS_TO_WAIT)
    return "Data received."

def main():
    n = 0

    while True:
        data = get_data()

        print(n)
        print(data)

        n += 1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I want the infinite loop not to block and keep printing the variable `n`, and only when `get_data()` function finishes its execution print the variable `data`. Note that we cannot change the `get_data()` function, because it is an imitation of an external library function, which we cannot change.

Here is a more precise example of my program and what I am trying to achieve:

```
import time

class LibraryWrapper():
    SECONDS_TO_WAIT = 3

    def __init__(self):
        # initialization of library

        self.data = None

    # imitation of an external library blocking function
    def get_data(self):
        time.sleep(self.SECONDS_TO_WAIT)
        return "Data received."


class Program():
    def __init__(self, library_wrapper):
        self.library_wrapper = library_wrapper

    def run(self, user_input):
        # do some stuff
        print(user_input)

        if library_wrapper.data:
            print(library_wrapper.data)


def main():
    library_wrapper = LibraryWrapper()

    program = Program(library_wrapper)

    user_input = 0

    while True:
        # read/imitate non-blocking user input
        user_input += 1

        library_wrapper.data = library_wrapper.get_data()

        program.run(user_input)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I guess the best solution to my problem might be the asyncio library. I have read the official documentation and got a basic understanding of coroutines, async and await keywords, tasks and futures.

I tried to run the following code to at least get an idea of how I can get the expected result, but it didn't give me that. The infinite loop was blocking even with the asyncio library.

```
import asyncio

SECONDS_TO_WAIT = 3

async def get_data():
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    return "Data received."

async def main():
    n = 0

    while True:
        task = asyncio.create_task(get_data())

        print(n)
        print(await task)

        n += 1

asyncio.run(main())

# 0
# 3 seconds passed...
# Data received.
# 1
# 3 seconds passed...
# Data received.
# 2
# 3 seconds passed...
# Data received.
# 3
```

I also looked at the following questions, here on stackoverflow, but they too didn't give me any idea how I could wrap a blocking function into a non-blocking function.

[How to use asyncio with existing blocking library?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41063331/12948018)
[How could I use requests in asyncio?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22190403/12948018)

Comment: When should a new execution of `get_data` start? After the previous execution finishes? Or on every iteration of the loop? If you want to start a new execution of `get_data` on every loop iteration, you're going to hit resource limits and/or outpace your ability to actually finish what you're starting.

Comment: You can also create a thread and run `get_data`?

Comment: @user2357112, yes, you make a valid point. Unfortunately, I don't understand the library I'm using very well and I can't determine if the request is pending or not. At least I know that it will return `NULL` if there is no new data. All I have is an [example](https://github.com/tdlib/td/blob/master/example/python/tdjson_example.py) from the authors of this library, which I'm sticking to.

Comment: @Corralien, yes, I've been thinking about it. I'll try to learn more about it and will write back if this solution solves the problem.

Comment: @someApp: Wait, that library is *already* non-blocking. Also, trying to have multiple calls to `td_receive` running at the same time is specifically documented as unsafe.

Comment: The example you linked to is using ctypes to access TDLib's C JSON interface, documented [here](https://core.telegram.org/tdlib/docs/td__json__client_8h.html). (If you're not familiar with ctypes, the documentation for that is [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html).)

Comment: (Elaborating on the "already non-blocking" comment, `td_receive` only blocks if you tell it to, and only as long as you tell it to. `td_execute` is blocking, but you don't need to use it.)

Comment: @user2357112, Thank you so much for your efforts to help me sort out a problem that is already beyond the scope of this issue! I'm indeed not familiar with ctypes. And I have a lot of questions. The first of which is how to tell the `td_recieve` function to become non-blocking. And I got the idea, not to set the object property of this function `_td_receive.argtypes` to `c_double`, and that solved my problem - the application stopped blocking. Thanks a lot, I don't know how to express my gratitude. You are just brilliant.

Comment: @someApp: I think you're supposed to keep the `_td_receive.argtypes = [c_double]`, but just pass it 0 as the number of seconds to wait.

Comment: @user2357112, yes, that's also works.

Comment: @user2357112, the solution to this problem doesn't seem logical to me. How did you figure out that the `td_receive` function could be non-blocking? The [reference](https://core.telegram.org/tdlib/docs/td__json__client_8h.html#a62715bea8e41a554d1bac763c187b662) to this function doesn't give any hint about that.

Comment: @someApp: The docs advertise the library as non-blocking, for example [here](https://core.telegram.org/tdlib/docs/index.html): "Fully-asynchronous: requests to TDLib don't block each other or anything else, responses are sent when they are available." The timeout parameter controls how long `td_receive` is allowed to wait for new data, so setting it to 0 tells the function not to wait at all.

Comment: @user2357112, I see, so the JSON interface was related to this as well. I had my doubts about it. And passing 0 to this function could have given an error about an invalid value. Ultimately, the problem was my lack of knowledge of Python and programming in general. I will do my best to improve my programming skills! Thank you very much for your efforts to help me.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I interpret your problem:

- You want to start a secondary task that takes 3 seconds.
- You want to run an infinite loop in the main task, while the secondary task runs.
- You want to print the result from the secondary task when it becomes available.
- Perhaps you want to re-start the secondary task.  I am assuming that you do.

The asyncio package does not know what you would like to do, so you need to write out the logic.  Like this:

```
import asyncio

SECONDS_TO_WAIT = 3

async def get_data():
    print("Task started")
    await asyncio.sleep(SECONDS_TO_WAIT)
    return "Data received."

async def main():
    n = 0

    task = asyncio.create_task(get_data())
    while True:
        print(n)
        if task.done():
            print("Task finished", task.result())
            task = asyncio.create_task(get_data())
        n += 1
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1)  # An await is needed to let other Tasks run

asyncio.run(main())
```

The reason why your approach doesn't work is that this expression:

```
await task
```

causes the execution of main() to stop right there until get_data is finished.  That is NOT what you want, so therefore you can't write your program that way.  You simply want to check if the `get_data` task is done.

When you start a secondary Task like this, a common problem is how to get the result back into your main Task.  My script handles this by polling to see if the secondary Task is done.  There are other tools available in the asyncio package.  For example, Task has a function called add_done_callback, which takes a function as an argument.  In this function you can print out the result and re-launch the Task if that's what you want.

Note that a second thread does not solve your problem.  You still have to wait for the second thread, and figure out a way to get the data back into main().

However, my preferred solution is to use the loop as a Task and print the results in main().  This is clearer, I think, since the loop has no interaction with get_data().

```
import asyncio

SECONDS_TO_WAIT = 3

async def get_data():
    print("Task started")
    await asyncio.sleep(SECONDS_TO_WAIT)
    return "Data received."

async def a_loop():
    n = 0
    while True:
        print(n)
        n += 1
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1)

async def main():
    asyncio.create_task(a_loop())
    while True:
        print(await get_data())

asyncio.run(main())
```

That also accomplishes what you want, is easier to understand and does not require polling.

Answer (score 0):

If you can not change get_data, and get_data is implemented as sycronus functions, your best and most simple bet whould be to create a thread to run get_data().

```
import threading
import time

# Create an event to signal that the data is ready.
data_ready_event = threading.Event()

# Function to run in the thread.
def get_data_thread():
    # Call the function as needed.
    data = get_data()
    # Set the event to signal that the work is done.
    data_ready_event.set()

def main():
    # Create a thread for get_data
    data_thread = threading.Thread(target=get_data_thread)

    # Start the thread
    data_thread.start()

    while (true):
        # Check if the event happned.
        if data_ready_event.is_set():
            pass # Instead of passwrite the relevent code when the function is done.  
        print(n) # Your print.

    # Wait for the data_thread to finish
    data_thread.join()

# Run the main function
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

As for transfering the Data from the thread, you have many options.
You can use pipe, shared memeory (such as a global fifo), etc.