# with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor: ... does not wait

Tags: python, threadpool, wait, threadpoolexecutor, concurrent.futures

I am trying to use the `ThreadPoolExecutor()` in a method of a class to create a pool of threads that will execute another method within the same class. I have the `with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor()...` however it does not wait, and an error is thrown saying there was no key in the dictionary I query after the "with..." statement. I understand why the error is thrown because the dictionary has not been updated yet because the threads in the pool did not finish executing. I know the threads did not finish executing because I have a print("done") in the method that is called within the ThreadPoolExecutor, and "done" is not printed to the console.

I am new to threads, so if any suggestions on how to do this better are appreciated!

```
    def tokenizer(self):
        all_tokens = []
        self.token_q = Queue()
        with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
            for num in range(5):
                executor.submit(self.get_tokens, num)
            executor.shutdown(wait=True)

        print("Hi")
        results = {}
        while not self.token_q.empty():
            temp_result = self.token_q.get()
            results[temp_result[1]] = temp_result[0]
            print(temp_result[1])
        for index in range(len(self.zettels)):
            for zettel in results[index]:
                all_tokens.append(zettel)
        return all_tokens

    def get_tokens(self, thread_index):
        print("!!!!!!!")
        switch = {
            0: self.zettels[:(len(self.zettels)/5)],
            1: self.zettels[(len(self.zettels)/5): (len(self.zettels)/5)*2],
            2: self.zettels[(len(self.zettels)/5)*2: (len(self.zettels)/5)*3],
            3: self.zettels[(len(self.zettels)/5)*3: (len(self.zettels)/5)*4],
            4: self.zettels[(len(self.zettels)/5)*4: (len(self.zettels)/5)*5],
        }
        new_tokens = []
        for zettel in switch.get(thread_index):
            tokens = re.split('\W+', str(zettel))
            tokens = list(filter(None, tokens))
            new_tokens.append(tokens)
        print("done")
        self.token_q.put([new_tokens, thread_index])
```

'''

Expected to see all `print("!!!!!!")` and `print("done")` statements before the `print ("Hi")` statement.
Actually shows the `!!!!!!!` then the `Hi`, then the `KeyError` for the results dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop over concurrent.futures.as_completed() as shown [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor-example). It will yield values as each thread completes.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! It helped show the error that was preventing the method from finishing, however it looked like the ThreadPool was not waiting. The error that showed up after adding this, showed that the list slices in the switch statement of get_tokens() were appearing as floats because I divided by 5, instead I needed to add a second / to make the result of the division an int. Thanks for the guidance @new-dev-123!

Answer (score 2):

As you have already found out, the pool *is* waiting; `print('done')` is never executed because presumably a `TypeError` raises earlier.
The pool does not directly wait for the tasks to finish, it waits for its worker threads to join, which implicitly requires the execution of the tasks to complete, one way (success) or the other (exception).

The reason you do not see that exception raising is because the task is wrapped in a [`Future`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#future-objects). A `Future`

> [...] encapsulates the asynchronous execution of a callable.

`Future` instances are returned by the executor's [`submit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor.submit) method and they allow to query the state of the execution and access whatever its outcome is.

That brings me to some remarks I wanted to make.

**The `Queue` in `self.token_q` seems unnecessary**
Judging by the code you shared, you only use this queue to pass the results of your tasks back to the `tokenizer` function. That's not needed, you can access that from the `Future` that the call to `submit` returns:

```
def tokenizer(self):
    all_tokens = []
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
        futures = [executor.submit(get_tokens, num) for num in range(5)]
        # executor.shutdown(wait=True) here is redundant, it is called when exiting the context:
        # https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/concurrent/futures/_base.py#L623

    print("Hi")
    results = {}
    for fut in futures:
        try:
            res = fut.result()
            results[res[1]] = res[0]
        except Exception:
            continue
    [...] 

def get_tokens(self, thread_index):
    [...]
    # instead of self.token_q.put([new_tokens, thread_index])
    return new_tokens, thread_index
```

**It is likely that your program does not benefit from using threads**
From the code you shared, it seems like the operations in `get_tokens` are CPU bound, rather than I/O bound. If you are running your program in CPython (or any other interpreter using a [Global Interpreter Lock](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock)), there will be no benefit from using threads in that case.

> In CPython, the **global interpreter lock**, or **GIL**,  is a mutex that protects access to Python objects, preventing multiple threads from executing Python bytecodes at once.

That means for any Python process, only one thread can execute at any given time. This is not so much of an issue if your task at hand is I/O bound, i.e. frequently pauses to wait for I/O (e.g. for data on a socket). If your tasks need to constantly execute bytecode in a processor, there's no benefit for pausing one thread to let another execute some instructions. In fact, the resulting context switches might even prove detrimental.
You might want to go for [parallelism instead of concurrency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050222/what-is-the-difference-between-concurrency-and-parallelism). Take a look at [`ProcessPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor) for this.
However, I recommend to benchmark your code running sequentially, concurrently and in parallel. Creating processes or threads comes at a cost and, depending on the task to complete, doing so might take longer than just executing one task after the other in a sequential manner.

As an aside, this looks a bit suspicious:

```
for index in range(len(self.zettels)):
    for zettel in results[index]:
        all_tokens.append(zettel)
```

`results` seems to always have five items, because `for num in range(5)`. If the length of `self.zettels` is greater than five, I'd expect a `KeyError` to raise here.
If `self.zettels` is guaranteed to have a length of five, then I'd see potential for some code optimization here.