# Concept of Child process and asynchronous programming is somehow same in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, process, child-process

In Child process we fork process into many process for parallel processing,
Also in the asynchronous programming we are executing many asynchronous code Parallelly.

So it means both are same . please help me to understand this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050222/what-is-the-difference-between-concurrency-and-parallelism

Answer (score 0):

Not super sure if this is what your'e asking but:  Each process running the node.js runtime will use the asynchronous runtime and execution model.  If you have 2 underlying processors or hardware threads available then two node.js processes may execute in parallel.  If only a single processor or hardware thread is available then it's not possible to achieve parallel execution, even with multiple node.js processes available.

- Single node.js process & multiple cores/hardware threads & node.js threadpool ([UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE](https://nodejs.org/api/all.html#cli_uv_threadpool_size_size)) supported operations -> possibly parallel
- Many node.js processes -> concurrent
- Many node.js processes & Multiple cores/hardware threads -> possibly parallel