# How to evaluate multiple functions on one generator using asyncio instead of threading?

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous, memory-management, python-asyncio, python-multithreading

## The Goal

This effort is towards creating an efficient solution to the following problem.

```py
source = lambda: range(1 << 24)  # for example
functions = (min, max, sum)  # for example
data = tuple(source())  # from some generator
results = tuple(f(data) for f in functions)
```

This works. The `source()` function generates however many values it may. They're put into a `tuple` called `data`. Then a series of `functions` are called with that `tuple` to give the `results`. These functions iterate over one given parameterized iterator once and then give their result. This is fine for small datasets. However, if `source()` generates many, many values, they must all be stored. This can hog memory.

### Possible solution

Something like...

```py
from typing import Callable, Iterable, Tuple, TypeVar

TI = TypeVar('TI')
TO = TypeVar('TO')


def magic_function(data: Iterable[TI], fxns: Iterable[Callable[[Iterable[TI]], TO]]) -> Tuple[TO, ...]:
    stored = tuple(data)  # memory hog, prohibitively
    return tuple(f(stored) for f in fxns)


source = lambda: range(1 << 24)  # for example
functions = (min, max, sum)  # for example
results = magic_function(source(), functions)
```

This is what I've been trying to do. This `magic_function()` would give the `data` iterator to some kind of internal asynchronous server. The `fxns` would then be given asynchronous clients -- which would appear to be normal iterators. The `fxns` can process these clients as iterators unmodified. The `fxns` cannot be modified. It is possible to do this with the `threading` module. The overhead would be horrendous, though.

### Extra clarity

This should be true.

```py
source = lambda: range(1 << 24)  # for example
functions = (min, max, sum)  # for example
if first_method:
    data = tuple(source())  # from some generator
    results = tuple(f(data) for f in functions)
else:
    results = magic_function(source(), functions)
```

Whether `first_method` is `True` or `False`, for `source()`'s same output and the same `functions`, the `results` should **always** match (for single-pass iterator-consuming `functions`). The first computes and stores the entire dataset. This can be absently wasteful and slow. The magic method ought to save memory with minimal overhead costs (both time and memory).

### Threading implementation

This is a working implementation using the `threading` module. It's *visibly* slow...

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
from collections import namedtuple
from random import randint
from statistics import geometric_mean, harmonic_mean, mean, median, median_high, median_low, mode
from threading import Event, Lock, Thread
from typing import *

''' https://pastebin.com/u4mTHfgc '''

int_iterable = Iterable[int]
_T = TypeVar('_T1', int, float)
_FXN_T = Callable[[int_iterable], _T]


class Server:
    _it: int_iterable
    slots: int
    edit_slots: Lock
    element: _T
    available: Event
    zero_slots: Event
    end: bool

    def __init__(self, it: int_iterable):
        self._it = it
        self.slots = 0
        self.edit_slots = Lock()
        self.available = Event()
        self.zero_slots = Event()
        self.end = False

    def server(self, queue_length: int):
        available = self.available
        zero_slots = self.zero_slots
        for v in self._it:
            self.slots = queue_length
            self.element = v
            zero_slots.clear()
            available.set()
            zero_slots.wait()
        self.slots = queue_length
        self.end = True
        zero_slots.clear()
        available.set()
        zero_slots.wait()

    def client(self) -> int_iterable:
        available = self.available
        zero_slots = self.zero_slots
        edit_slots = self.edit_slots
        while True:
            available.wait()
            end = self.end
            if not end:
                yield self.element
            with edit_slots:
                self.slots -= 1
                if self.slots == 0:
                    available.clear()
                    zero_slots.set()
            zero_slots.wait()
            if end:
                break


class Slot:
    thread: Thread
    fxn: _FXN_T
    server: Server
    qid: int
    result: Union[Optional[_T], Exception, Tuple[Exception, Exception]]

    def __init__(self, fxn: _FXN_T, server: Server, qid: int):
        self.thread = Thread(target = self.run, name = f'BG {id(self)} thread {qid}')
        self.fxn = fxn
        self.server = server
        self.qid = qid
        self.result = None

    def run(self):
        client = self.server.client()
        try:
            self.result = self.fxn(client)
        except Exception as e:
            self.result = e
            try:
                for _ in client:  # one thread breaking won't break it all.
                    pass
            except Exception as f:
                self.result = e, f


class BranchedGenerator:
    _server: Server
    _queue: List[Slot]

    def __init__(self, it: int_iterable):
        self._server = Server(it)
        self._queue = []

    def new(self, fxn: _FXN_T) -> int:
        qid = len(self._queue)
        self._queue.append(Slot(fxn, self._server, qid))
        return qid

    def finalize(self):
        queue = self._queue
        for t in queue:
            t.thread.start()
        self._server.server(len(queue))
        for t in queue:
            t.thread.join()

    def get(self, qid: int) -> _T:
        return self._queue[qid].result

    @classmethod
    def make(cls, it: int_iterable, fxns: Iterable[_FXN_T]) -> Tuple[_T, ...]:
        tmp = cls(it)
        qid_range = max(map(tmp.new, fxns))
        tmp.finalize()
        return tuple((tmp.get(qid)) for qid in range(qid_range + 1))


seq_stats = namedtuple('seq_stats', ('tuple', 'mean', 'harmonic_mean', 'geometric_mean', 'median', 'median_high', 'median_low', 'mode'))


def bundle_bg(xs: int_iterable) -> seq_stats:
    tmp = BranchedGenerator(xs)
    # noinspection PyTypeChecker
    ys = seq_stats(
        tmp.new(tuple),
        tmp.new(mean),
        tmp.new(harmonic_mean),
        tmp.new(geometric_mean),
        tmp.new(median),
        tmp.new(median_high),
        tmp.new(median_low),
        tmp.new(mode)
    )
    tmp.finalize()
    return seq_stats(
        tmp.get(ys.tuple),
        tmp.get(ys.mean),
        tmp.get(ys.harmonic_mean),
        tmp.get(ys.geometric_mean),
        tmp.get(ys.median),
        tmp.get(ys.median_high),
        tmp.get(ys.median_low),
        tmp.get(ys.mode)
    )


def bundle(xs: int_iterable) -> seq_stats:
    return seq_stats(
        tuple(xs),
        mean(xs),
        harmonic_mean(xs),
        geometric_mean(xs),
        median(xs),
        median_high(xs),
        median_low(xs),
        mode(xs)
    )


def display(v: seq_stats):
    print(f'Statistics of {v.tuple}:\n'
          f'\tMean: {v.mean}\n'
          f'\tHarmonic Mean: {v.harmonic_mean}\n'
          f'\tGeometric Mean: {v.geometric_mean}\n'
          f'\tMedian: {v.median}\n'
          f'\tMedian High: {v.median_high}\n'
          f'\tMedian Low: {v.median_low}\n'
          f'\tMode: {v.mode};')


def new(length: int, inclusive_maximum: int) -> int_iterable:
    return (randint(1, inclusive_maximum) for _ in range(length))


def test1() -> int:
    sample = new(10, 1 << 65)
    struct1 = bundle_bg(sample)
    display(struct1)
    struct2 = bundle(struct1.tuple)
    display(struct2)
    matches = seq_stats(*(a == b for (a, b) in zip(struct1, struct2)))
    display(matches)
    return sum(((1 >> i) * (not e)) for (i, e) in enumerate(matches))


def test2():
    sample = new(1000, 1 << 5)
    struct1 = seq_stats(*BranchedGenerator.make(
        sample,
        (tuple, mean, harmonic_mean, geometric_mean, median, median_high, median_low, mode)
    ))
    display(struct1)
    struct2 = bundle(struct1.tuple)
    display(struct2)
    matches = seq_stats(*(a == b for (a, b) in zip(struct1, struct2)))
    display(matches)
    return sum(((1 >> i) * (not e)) for (i, e) in enumerate(matches))


def test3():
    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    exit((test2()))
```

The [Branching Generator Module (V3) [using threading] - Pastebin.com](https://pastebin.com/u4mTHfgc) link has the updated code. From Start to output, a half second elapses. That's just for eight functions!  Both `test1()` and `test2()` have this speed issue.

## Attempts

I have tried to implement `magic_function()` using the `asyncio` module.

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
from asyncio import Task, create_task, run, wait
from collections import deque, namedtuple
from random import randint
from statistics import geometric_mean, harmonic_mean, mean, median, median_high, median_low, mode
from typing import *

''' https://pastebin.com/ELzEaSK8 '''

int_iterable = Iterable[int]
_T = TypeVar('_T1', int, float)
ENGINE_T = AsyncGenerator[Tuple[_T, bool], int]


async def injector(engine: ENGINE_T, qid: int) -> AsyncIterator[int]:
    while True:
        try:
            x, try_again = await engine.asend(qid)
        except StopAsyncIteration:
            break
        if try_again:
            continue
        yield x


WRAPPER_FXN_T = Callable[[int_iterable], _T]


def wrapper(fxn: WRAPPER_FXN_T, engine: ENGINE_T, qid: int):
    async def i():
        # TypeError: 'async_generator' object is not iterable
        return fxn(iter(x async for x in injector(engine, qid)))

    return i


class BranchedGenerator:
    _it: int_iterable
    _engine: ENGINE_T
    _queue: Union[tuple, deque]

    def __init__(self, it: int_iterable):
        self._it = it
        self._engine = self._make_engine()
        # noinspection PyTypeChecker
        wait(self._engine)
        self._queue = deque()

    async def _make_engine(self) -> ENGINE_T:  # it's like a server
        lq = len(self._queue)
        result = try_again = 0, True
        for value in self._it:
            waiting = set(range(lq))
            while True:
                qid = (yield result)
                if len(waiting) == 0:
                    result = try_again
                    break
                if qid in waiting:
                    waiting.remove(qid)
                    result = value, False
                else:
                    result = try_again

    def new(self, fxn: WRAPPER_FXN_T) -> int:
        qid = len(self._queue)
        self._queue.append(wrapper(fxn, self._engine, qid)())
        return qid

    def finalize(self):
        self._queue = tuple(self._queue)

    def get(self, qid: int) -> Task:
        return create_task(self._queue[qid])

    @classmethod
    @(lambda f: (lambda it, fxns: run(f(it, fxns))))
    def make(cls, it: int_iterable, fxns: Iterable[Callable[[int_iterable], _T]]) -> Tuple[_T, ...]:
        tmp = cls(it)
        qid_range = max(map(tmp.new, fxns))
        tmp.finalize()
        return tuple((await tmp.get(qid)) for qid in range(qid_range + 1))


seq_stats = namedtuple('seq_stats', ('tuple', 'mean', 'harmonic_mean', 'geometric_mean', 'median', 'median_high', 'median_low', 'mode'))


@(lambda f: (lambda xs: run(f(xs))))
async def bundle_bg(xs: int_iterable) -> seq_stats:
    tmp = BranchedGenerator(xs)
    # noinspection PyTypeChecker
    ys = seq_stats(
        tmp.new(tuple),
        tmp.new(mean),
        tmp.new(harmonic_mean),
        tmp.new(geometric_mean),
        tmp.new(median),
        tmp.new(median_high),
        tmp.new(median_low),
        tmp.new(mode)
    )
    tmp.finalize()
    return seq_stats(
        await tmp.get(ys.tuple),
        await tmp.get(ys.mean),
        await tmp.get(ys.harmonic_mean),
        await tmp.get(ys.geometric_mean),
        await tmp.get(ys.median),
        await tmp.get(ys.median_high),
        await tmp.get(ys.median_low),
        await tmp.get(ys.mode)
    )


def bundle(xs: int_iterable) -> seq_stats:
    return seq_stats(
        tuple(xs),
        mean(xs),
        harmonic_mean(xs),
        geometric_mean(xs),
        median(xs),
        median_high(xs),
        median_low(xs),
        mode(xs)
    )


def display(v: seq_stats):
    print(f'Statistics of {v.tuple}:\n'
          f'\tMean: {v.mean}\n'
          f'\tHarmonic Mean: {v.harmonic_mean}\n'
          f'\tGeometric Mean: {v.geometric_mean}\n'
          f'\tMedian: {v.median}\n'
          f'\tMedian High: {v.median_high}\n'
          f'\tMedian Low: {v.median_low}\n'
          f'\tMode: {v.mode};')


def new(length: int, inclusive_maximum: int) -> int_iterable:
    return (randint(1, inclusive_maximum) for _ in range(length))


def test1() -> int:
    sample = new(10, 1 << 65)
    struct1 = bundle_bg(sample)
    display(struct1)
    struct2 = bundle(struct1.tuple)
    display(struct2)
    matches = seq_stats(*(a == b for (a, b) in zip(struct1, struct2)))
    display(matches)
    return sum(((1 >> i) * (not e)) for (i, e) in enumerate(matches))


async def test2():
    sample = new(1000, 1 << 5)
    # noinspection PyTypeChecker
    struct1 = seq_stats(*await BranchedGenerator.make(
        sample,
        (tuple, mean, harmonic_mean, geometric_mean, median, median_high, median_low, mode)
    ))
    display(struct1)
    struct2 = bundle(struct1.tuple)
    display(struct2)
    matches = seq_stats(*(a == b for (a, b) in zip(struct1, struct2)))
    display(matches)
    return sum(((1 >> i) * (not e)) for (i, e) in enumerate(matches))


async def test3():
    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    exit((test1()))
```

The [Branching Generator Module (V2) - Pastebin.com](https://pastebin.com/ELzEaSK8) link has the most up-to-date version. I will *not* be updating the embedded code! If changes are made, the pastebin copy will have them.

### Tests

1. The `test1()` makes sure that `bundle_bg()` does what `bundle()` does. They should do the exact same thing.
2. The `test2()` sees if `BranchedGenarator.make()` behaves like `bundle_bg()` and (transitively) like `bundle()`. The `BranchedGenarator.make()` is supposed to be most like `magic_function()`.
3. `test3()` has no purpose yet.

### Status

The first test fails. The second test has a similar error calling `BranchedGenerator.make()`.

```
[redacted]/b_gen.py:45: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'wait' was never awaited
  wait(self._engine)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[redacted]/b_gen.py", line 173, in <module>
    exit((test1()))
  File "[redacted]/b_gen.py", line 144, in test1
    struct1 = bundle_bg(sample)
  File "[redacted]/b_gen.py", line 87, in <lambda>
    @(lambda f: (lambda xs: run(f(xs))))
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 642, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "[redacted]/b_gen.py", line 103, in bundle_bg
    await tmp.get(ys.tuple),
  File "[redacted]/b_gen.py", line 31, in i
    return fxn(iter(x async for x in injector(engine, qid)))
TypeError: 'async_generator' object is not iterable
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'wrapper.<locals>.i' was never awaited
```

In all honesty, I'm new to `asyncio`. I don't know how to fix this.

### The Question

Can somebody help me fix this?! Please? This one with `asyncio` should do exactly what the one with `threading` does -- just without the overhead.

## Another pathway

Before this, I attempted a simpler implementation.

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
from random import randrange
from statistics import mean as st_mean, median as st_median, mode as st_mode
from typing import Any, Callable, Iterable, Tuple, TypeVar

''' https://pastebin.com/xhfT1njJ '''


class BranchedGenerator:
    _n: Iterable[int]
    _stop_value: Any

    def __init__(self, n: Iterable[int], stop: Any):
        self._n = n
        self._stop_value = stop

    @property
    def new(self):
        return


def wrapper1(f):
    new = (yield)
    # SyntaxError: 'yield' inside generator expression
    yield f((y for _ in new if (y := (yield)) or True))
    return


_T1 = TypeVar('_T1')
_T2 = TypeVar('_T2')


def wrapper2(ns: Iterable[_T1], fs: Iterable[Callable[[Iterable[_T1]], _T2]]) -> Tuple[_T2, ...]:
    def has_new():
        while new:
            yield True
        while True:
            yield False

    new = True
    xwf = tuple(map(wrapper1, fs))
    for x in xwf:
        next(x)
        x.send(has_new)
        next(x)
    for n in ns:
        for x in xwf:
            x.send(n)
    new = False
    return tuple(map(next, xwf))


def source(n: int) -> Iterable[int]:
    return (randrange(-9, 9000) for _ in range(n))


normal = (tuple, st_mean, st_median, st_mode)


def test0():
    sample = tuple(source(25))
    s_tuple, s_mean, s_median, s_mode = wrapper2(sample, normal)
    b_tuple, b_mean, b_median, b_mode = (f(s_tuple) for f in normal)
    assert all((
        s_tuple == b_tuple,
        s_mean == b_mean,
        s_median == b_median,
        s_mode == b_mode
    ))


def test1():
    sample = source(25)
    s_tuple, s_mean, s_median, s_mode = wrapper2(sample, normal)
    b_tuple, b_mean, b_median, b_mode = (f(s_tuple) for f in normal)
    print(
        'Test1:'
        '\nTuple', s_tuple, '\n', b_tuple, '\n==?', v0 := s_tuple == b_tuple,
        '\nMean', s_mean, '\n', b_mean, '\n==?', v1 := s_mean == b_mean,
        '\nMedian', s_median, '\n', b_median, '\n==?', v2 := s_median == b_median,
        '\nMode', s_mode, '\n', b_mode, '\n==?', v3 := s_mode == b_mode,
        '\nPasses', ''.join('01'[v * 1] for v in (v0, v1, v2, v3)), 'All?', all((v0, v1, v2, v3))
    )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test0()
    test1()
```

The [Branching Generator Module (V1) - Pastebin.com](https://pastebin.com/xhfT1njJ) link has the update policy.

### Tests

1. Test 0 tells whether `wrapper2()` does what is supposed to do. That is to call all `functions` and return the results. No memory is saved, like `first_method == True`.
2. Test 1 is simply like `first_method == False`. The `sample` is not a `tuple`.

### Problem

Ouch! I can code, I assure you.

```
 File "[redacted]/branched_generator.py", line 25
    yield f((y for _ in new if (y := (yield)) or True))
            ^
SyntaxError: 'yield' inside generator expression
```

I freely admit it: this version is dafter. The `wrapper2()` is obviously most like `magic_function()`.

### Question

As this is the simpler implementation, can this `wrapper2()` be salvaged? If not, don't sweat it.

Comment: Have you considered Gevent https://sdiehl.github.io/gevent-tutorial/ - it would be interesting to see the implementation if you have tried it

Comment: @DeepakGarud Gevent looks awesome.  Is it fast?

Comment: In the linked document, they have shown some comparisons, may be that will give an idea

Answer (score 0):

If it's just the materialization of the data you are worried about, you could do

```py
from itertools import tee
from statistics import geometric_mean, harmonic_mean, mean, median, median_high, median_low, mode
from random import randint

def magic_function(data, fxns):
    return tuple(f(d) for f, d in zip(fxns, tee(data, len(fxns))))

def new(length: int, inclusive_maximum: int) -> Iterable[int]:
    return (randint(1, inclusive_maximum) for _ in range(length))

sample = new(1000, 1 << 5)
functions = (tuple, mean, harmonic_mean, geometric_mean, median, median_high, median_low, mode)

magic_function(sample, functions)
```

NB [`tee`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=tee#itertools.tee) is not thread-safe though

PS: You are right, this consumes the generator and makes n copies of all data in it.

I don't think we can salvage the *async* and *await* version in your question. The arbitrary functions in fxns will have to consume the iterators asynchronously; they have to release control flow after (roughly) each item they pop off and process. But *async* and *await* are cooperative, we can't force any given function *f* to *await* in its loop (that's why we get the `TypeError`). But your solution using `threading` **does** work, because at some points in their loops, threads are put to sleep pre-emptively by the VM, and in that way give opportunity for the other functions to run.

Keep in mind, there's a [difference between simultaneous and concurrent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1050257/383793). When I said a sequential roundrobin of the functions would be enough, I meant it in this way, let one of them consume an item, and then let the next one consume one. There is no need for the functions to run simultaneous. In fact, your working threading example, doesn't run anything simultaneously (on the CPython VM. IronPython and Jython may run multiple `threading.Thread`s simultaneously, but on CPython there's only 1 running at a time)

Comment: This stores data.  The point is not to store data.

Comment: It does duplicaye the iterator, however the functions still need to be called simultaneously to avoid storing data.

Comment: It only stores n copies of 1 value at the time, where n is the number of functions, if you roundrobin the functions. You don't have to call the functions simultaneously, just sequentially.

Comment: We can update the answer to do that. I first need to caffeinate and get to a keyboard.

Comment: Note to self, don't check your SO inbox when you just wake up; it makes you overestimate the power of caffeine.

Comment: I don't follow.  I want each function to get the exact same sequence.  Calling the functions sequencially spends the generator on the first function and the functions thereafter cannot get those same values without storing them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232120/discussion-between-youngcoder5-and-chris-wesseling).