# How does Dart/Flutter execute code concurrently even if it's single threaded?

Tags: multithreading, flutter, dart

I'm new to Dart/Flutter and have some Node.js background, I understand that Dart has some similarities with Node.js like event loop and single threaded. But I have a hard time understanding how Dart handles `async` for blocking I/O operation, especially internal I/O like file system and database operation.

For Node.js, when it handles blocking I/O, let's say read the content of a file. It puts that file system operation in the `Thread Pool`, Node.js then concurrently (not parallelly) runs the next line of code in the main thread while the file system operation keep running. When it finishes reading the file, it puts a read-file callback event in the `Event Queue` which will be dequeued by `Event Loop` and be executed in the main thread. The concept of Node.js is not hard to understand, but how about Dart?

As Dart has no `Thread Pool` or something similar to Node.js's, it's single threaded and the official site says it runs everything in the main thread, whether it find `Future`, `async`, or anything like that, it still runs in the main thread, when it finishes that operation, it then puts the callback in `Event Queue` waiting for being dequeued by `Event Loop` and executed in the main thread.

This leads to my confusion that Dart can still run the next line of code while file system operation (blocking I/O) is still running. Please have a look at this piece of code

```
File myFile = File("some-text-file");
myFile.readAsString().then((content) {
  print(content);
});
print("This is my next line");
```

output:

```
This is my next line
Lorem ipsum...
```

How is that possible by not blocking the I/O operation without utilizing `Thread Pool` or something similar to Node.js's? If it was Node.js, `myFile.readAsString()` will be delegated to `Thread Pool` for concurrency.

Or Dart indeed under the hood simply spawn a new `Isolate` for that blocking I/O operation?

Thank you in advance for all of your answers.

Answer (score 1):

1. [Concurrency is not the same as parallelism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050222/what-is-the-difference-between-concurrency-and-parallelism).  You don't need multiple threads to be concurrent.
2. Each Dart *[isolate](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.4/dart-isolate/Isolate-class.html)* is single-threaded, but a Dart program can have multiple isolates.
3. In most cases, an asynchronous operation ultimately executes some lower-level operation implemented outside of Dart (such as in the Dart VM/runtime or via an FFI binding) where they can spawn OS threads, spawn separate processes, or perhaps perform filesystem operations that performs asynchronous I/O. It depends the implementation of the asynchronous operation.