# Asynchronous, synchronous and concurrency in Dart

Tags: dart, asynchronous, async-await

According to what I saw on the dart official website, functions that do not use the async and await keywords that return a Future object are synchronous functions, and functions that use the async and await keywords are asynchronous functions.

[synchronous functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ARSX.png)
[asynchronous functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOskV.png)

First, I think that the part expressed as a synchronous function is more like an asynchronous function, and the part expressed as an asynchronous function is more like a synchronous function. A synchronous function that does not block code execution appears to have asynchronous characteristics. How should I understand this part?

Second, I confirmed on the official site that the main function is executed in the main isolate. In terms of 'concurrency', how can the await function and the function executed in the main function be executed simultaneously in a single thread (I know that dart is single-threaded)? Where and how it be possible?

I read https://dart.dev/language/concurrency and follow https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-awaitn as well. And also I've been searching async and concurrency keyword.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> According to what I saw on the dart official website, functions that do not use the async and await keywords that return a Future object are synchronous functions, and functions that use the async and await keywords are asynchronous functions.

No, a function that returns a `Future` is asynchronous, regardless of whether it uses the `async` keyword.  The `async` keyword enables the use of the `await` keyword (`async`-`await` were not originally part of the Dart language) and automatically makes all `return` statements return `Future`s.  I think the example you saw is misleading when taken out of context; it's probably attempting to demonstrate what happens when you attempt to call an asynchronous function from a synchronous function, not claiming that all functions listed in the example are synchronous.

> A synchronous function that does not block code execution appears to have asynchronous characteristics. How should I understand this part?

Yes.

> Second, I confirmed on the official site that the main function is executed in the main isolate. In terms of 'concurrency', how can the await function and the function executed in the main function be executed simultaneously in a single thread (I know that dart is single-threaded)? Where and how it be possible?

You are conflating *concurrency* with *parallelism*.  See: [How does Dart/Flutter execute code concurrently even if it's single threaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67240076/)