# How to allow Child Process listen to TCP or Socket on RUST

Tags: rust, concurrency, rust-tokio, rust-axum

I am trying to write a service that listens to socket for local and port for remote request. However, when I fork new process, the child process cannot create tcpListener nor UnixListener. It gave me bad file descripor/failed to wake io driver error

```
process num: 0, pid: 51782 => cidr: 0.0.0.0:8000, socks: /tmp/srv/rust-uds-0.sock
process num: 1, pid: 51794 => cidr: 0.0.0.0:8001, socks: /tmp/src/rust-uds-1.sock
thread 'main' panicked at src/main.rs:109:57:
called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Os { code: 9, kind: Uncategorized, message: "Bad file descriptor" }
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
thread 'main' panicked at /Users/xxxxx/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/tokio-1.34.0/src/runtime/io/driver.rs:209:27:
failed to wake I/O driver: Os { code: 9, kind: Uncategorized, message: "Bad file descriptor" }
```

In my code I have

```
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let args = Args::parse();

    //uses nix fork and just returns a proc index for printing
    let proc_idx = fork_service(args.numprocs).await;

    let tcp_cidr = format!("0.0.0.0:{}", args.port + proc_idx);
    let socket_path = format!("{}/rust-uds-{}.sock", socket_dir, proc_idx);
    println!("process idx: {}, pid: {} => cidr: {}, socks: {}", proc_idx, id(), tcp_cidr, socket_path);

    // build our application with a single route
    let app = Router::new()
    .route("/", get(index))
    .route("/healthcheck", get(healthcheck))
    .route("/delay/:seconds", get(delay));

    // process http request from remote machine
    let tcplistener = TcpListener::bind(tcp_cidr).await.unwrap();
    axum::serve(tcplistener, app).await.unwrap();
}
```

I am confused on why this would failed cuz the listener is created after the fork, so there are not sharing. If args.numproc == 1, then everything works perfectly.
please help

Comment: Why are you forking your process?

Comment: You are forking **inside** tokio runtime and it somehow messes with its IO event driver (look at the source of the panic). If you _really_ want to fork (although I don't know what that would give you), make `main` a non-async function, fork at the start of it, and then manually create a runtime and pass your async function (or just mark any function as `#[tokio::main]` and then call it from the normal `main` function`).

Comment: I want to fork so I can process more request concurrently? the request the service plan on handling may take a while to process, they are more cpu bound. I am new to rust and am thinking from my python background. @AleksanderKrauze

Comment: Then how do you synchronize forked processes with each other? I would *strongly* discourage messing with forking processes in rust if you don't have a strong reason for doing so (one reason could be daemonisation), especially if you are beginning with rust. There is almost nothing you can't do with plan OS thread that you can do with forked process, and using threads is so much simpler and safer in rust than processes. See [std::thread](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/index.html) module.

Comment: But even this isn't always necessary. You can run blocking (CPU bound) code in tokio if you are careful enough. Read [tokio's documentation](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/index.html#cpu-bound-tasks-and-blocking-code) on that topic.

Comment: @AleksanderKrauze thank you so much for your help. So if multithreads from one process can run on multiple cores concurrently, that means there is no need for me to fork multiple process at all? is that correct? What I am currently doing is then unnecessary? I think my mindset was stuck on python GIL.

Comment: Yes. Multiple OS threads can be executed in parallel on multiple CPU cores. "Multithreading" and "multiprocessing" in python and indeed quite different than everywhere else. You can study this SO thread on differences between [concurrency and parallelism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050222/what-is-the-difference-between-concurrency-and-parallelism) to better understand differences between this two concepts and how do they relate to OS processes, threads, green threads etc.

Comment: I can't think of a reason you'd want to fork and use an async runtime at the same time, except possibly to daemonize on startup. The async runtime will manage threads and concurrency for you, just make sure you use `spawn_blocking` if you need to run code that is highly CPU-bound.