# Parallelism for processing RGB Images not improving runtime

Tags: python, image-processing, parallel-processing

For curiosity's sake, I am experimenting with image compression by using SVD. When I iteratively process each channel (R,G,B), each iteration takes around 20 seconds. The overall time comes out to ~75 seconds.

I assumed that processing the three channels in parallel would reduce the overall time to ~20 seconds, but after timing my functions, each channel takes 70 seconds to process now and the overall time is still ~75 seconds.

No Parallelism

```
channels = [image_data[:, :, i] for i in range(image_data.shape[2])]
        compressed_image_data = np.zeros((image_data.shape[0],image_data.shape[1], image_data.shape[2]))
        for i,channel in enumerate(channels):
                svd_start_time = time.time()
                channel_u, channel_s, channel_v = np.linalg.svd(channel, full_matrices=False)
                print(type(channel_u))
                svd_end_time = time.time()
                print(f"SVD computation time: {svd_end_time - svd_start_time}")
                mat_mul_time_start = time.time()
                print("Hello, it will crash on the next line")
                k_rank_approx = channel_u[:, 0:k].dot(np.diag(channel_s[0:k]).dot(channel_v[0:k,:]))
                mat_mul_time_end = time.time()
                print(f"Matrix multiplication time: {mat_mul_time_end - mat_mul_time_start}")
                print("Bytes required for compressed image: " + str(channel_u[:,0:k].nbytes + np.diag(channel_s[0:k]).nbytes + channel_v[0:k,:].nbytes))
                compressed_image_data[:,:,i] = k_rank_approx
```

With Parallelism

```
def svd(channel, k_rank):
        """
        Returns the k-rank approximation of an RGB channel using SVD
        """
        start_time = time.time()
        u, s, v = np.linalg.svd(channel, full_matrices=False)
        end_time = time.time()
        print(f'SVD computation: {end_time-start_time}')
        start_time = time.time()
        k_rank_approx = u[:, 0:k_rank].dot(np.diag(s[0:k_rank]).dot(v[0:k_rank, :]))
        end_time = time.time()
        print(f'Low Rank Approximation: {end_time-start_time}')
        return k_rank_approx

def process_image(input_filename, output_folder, k):
        # Construct the full path
        input_image_path = os.path.join("images", input_filename)
        partial_svd = partial(svd, k_rank=k)
        image = Image.open(input_image_path)
        image_data = np.array(image)
        result = []
        print("Bytes required for original image: " + str(image_data.nbytes))
        # Separate color channels
        channels = [image_data[:, :, i] for i in range(image_data.shape[2])]
        compressed_image_data = np.zeros((image_data.shape[0],image_data.shape[1], image_data.shape[2]))
        print("Starting multiprocessing...")
        with Pool(3) as p:
                result = p.map(partial_svd, channels)
        print("Assembling results...")
        for i,channel in enumerate(result):
                compressed_image_data[:,:,i] = channel
```

Not too sure about what causes this behavior.

Comment: The first question is whether it really runs the processes in parallel, or merely concurrently (see [concurrency vs parallelism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050222/what-is-the-difference-between-concurrency-and-parallelism)). 
What is the result of calling `os.cpu_count()`?

Comment: Without knowing the specifics of how you process the image, it could also be that the actual processing of a channel is not what is taking up most of the time. You could look into this with a [profiler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html)

Comment: Matrix multiplication is already parallel. AFAIK the SVD computation is also parallel (and generally particularly expensive). Based on this, using more processes, will just slow things down since there are certainly enough threads to saturate cores. You can check that by running a simple OS task manager.

Comment: @Soenderby I added a print statement at the top of the file. When I run the file, 8 is printed 4 times. I'm guessing this is because of the main process + 3 child processes that I spawned.