A formal+didactic+schematic explanation of concurrency vs parallelism
tl;dr I think I have understood the concurrency vs parallelism examples below, but only really to the extent of those examples, and I'd like to get a more formal explanation that would allow (or help) me to understand and digest this concept to the point that I don't have to remember the two examples below to (re-)convince myself everytime of the difference, but that I can just make up such examples, because I've truly understood it in "mathemtatical" terms.

In this presentation at CppCon 2019 Daisy Hollman shows this snippet of concurrent code,
std::atomic<int> x = {0};

// worker A
while (x.load() == 0) {}
cout << "Hello" << endl;

// worker B
x.store(1);

and compares it with one way of serializing it,
// serial
std::atomic<int> x = {0};
while (x.load() == 0) {}
cout << "Hello" << endl;
x.store(1);

in order to drive the point home that

concurrency is a stronger scheduling guarantee than serial

I understand those words in the sense that concurrency allows to schedule the tasks in such a way that their executions is guaranteed to happen in a way that cannot be guaranteed by a serial execution. In the specific example above, the tasks A and B happen concurrently, which guarantees that sooner or later x.store(1); will execute, which in turns guarantees that the condition of the while loop in the other thread will be false, allowing that thread to continue.
The slide closes with

When you use serial execution for the program with concurrent requirements, it (obviously) never prints hello.

What are the "concurrent requirements"? Is the requirement(s) that worker B should not wait for worker A to complete, but should run concurrently with it?

Then an almost symmetric claim is made,

parallelism is a weaker scheduling requirement than serial

supported by this parallel code
int x = 0;

// worker A
x += 1; // not atomic operation

// worker B
x += 1; // not atomic operation

versus this serial code,
// serial code
int x = 0;
x += 1;
x += 1;

In this case, if the two tasks are working in parallel, than 2 outcomes are possible (x == 1 or x == 2), whereas if they are executed serially, then only 1 outcome is possible (x == 2)
This slides closes with

When you use serial execution for the program with parallel requirements, it (obviously) results in x == 2.

What are the "parallel requirements"? Is it the lack of the requirement that the output of the program is 2?

Then another slide reads


When you use concurrent features to express parallelism, you end up with unreasonable overheads.
The programming model is not restrictive enough for the compiler or runtime system to avoid these overheads.


And the way I understand that, is that concurrent features are expressing more scheduling guarantees that a parallel program requires, and those guarantee have a cost at compile time in the sense that the compiler can write code, and the runtime can't execute code, with the assumption that the tasks in the parallel program do not need to take into account each other.

Despite I think I understood the examples and the general idea, I think I would really benefit of a more formal explanation of what requirement, guarantee, strong and weak mean in this context.
For instance, I'm having a hard time to put together

concurrency being a stronger scheduling guarantee than serial
concurrency model being not restrictive enough

The first point makes me think of "strong", the second makes me think of "weak", which sound contraddictory adjectives, but I don't think they are, because they predicate different things.

The formal definition is here. It doesn't use the terms "concurrency" or "parallelism", I'm not sure what the presenter meant by them or what distinction they draw between them. Nor do I understand what they mean by "serializing".

The second example is straight up undefined behavior in C++. Any outcome at all is possible.

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050222/what-is-the-difference-between-concurrency-and-parallelism

Related, but not the answer, @ThomasWeller.

The difference between concurrency and parallelism is simple, and it's explained by many answers on this site. In a nutshell: "Concurrency" is a purely software concept. You have concurrency when your program gives permission for certain parts of it to be executed in no particular order with respect to certain other parts of it. "Parallelism" is a hardware thing. You have parallelism when the hardware makes simultaneous use of more execution units than it would have needed to perform all of the steps of your program one-by-one. Parallel execution requires a concurrent program.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_(computer_science) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_computing https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Execution_unit
