# what is coroutine?

Tags: programming-languages

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is coroutine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553704/what-is-coroutine)

coroutine appears in this nodejs thread.

http://groups.google.com/group/nodejs/msg/df199d233ff17efa

Comment: Please help yourself, just a bit, before posting onto SO.  Had you checked say Wikipedia or Google, you'd probably be able to answer this question, or to ask a more specific, informed, question.

Comment: In fact, searching "coroutine" in SO itself, yield a lot a very relevant, indeed duplicate questions...  ex: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/553704/what-is-coroutine