# How can I return the response before the execution of the function using Aiohttp library?

Tags: python, aiohttp

Actually I want to return a response whenever a request is fired and then execute the task asynchronously so that the client has to not wait for a long to get the response.For that, I am using "Aiohttp" library as I want to perform async tasks.

Can anyone guide me on how can i achieve this in aiohttp?

Comment: There're examples from official site: https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp Is there anything specific you want to know?

Comment: Yes knh190 , actually in the given examples on the official documentation or the link that you mentioned , they return the web_response after the execution of the task.But, suppose your task is quite long and if a client fires a request , then the client has to wait a long for receiving the response and instead what I want is that as soon as the request is fired , the reponse is sent to the client and task is added to the eventloop for execution and it takes its time then.

Comment: The response is async. It's not blocking the execution of main loop. So I don't see there a problem. For more explained details about coroutines, see [this post](https://github.com/AndreLouisCaron/a-tale-of-event-loops) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553704/what-is-a-coroutine) for brief.

Comment: `httpio` is made for the purpose of executing non-blocking requests. The execution will be handed over to main loop when waiting for a response, without trivial coding.

Comment: ok , thanks for the help. I'll try if I get the correct solution from this.

Comment: `aiojobs` will help you (https://github.com/aio-libs/aiojobs)