# What is 'pytest.mark.asyncio' is used for?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, pytest-asyncio

I don't understand for which purposes the decorator `@pytest.mark.asyncio` can be used.

I've tried to run the following code snippet with `pytest` and `pytest-asyncio` plugin installed and it failed, so I concluded that pytest collects test coroutines without the decorator. Why it exists so?

```py
async def test_div():
    return 1 / 0
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

When your tests are marked with `@pytest.mark.asyncio`, they become [coroutines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553704/what-is-a-coroutine), together with the keyword `await` in body

`pytest` will execute it as an asyncio task using the event loop provided by the `event_loop` fixture:

This code with decorator

```
@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_example(event_loop):
    do_stuff()    
    await asyncio.sleep(0.1, loop=event_loop)
```

is equal to writing this:

```
def test_example():
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    try:
        do_stuff()
        asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
        loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.sleep(0.1, loop=loop))
    finally:
        loop.close()
```

### Note / Update

As of `pytest-asyncio>=0.17` if you add `asyncio_mode = auto` to your config (`pyproject.toml`, `setup.cfg` or `pytest.ini`) there is no need for the marker, i.e. this behaviour is enabled for async tests automatically.

See https://pytest-asyncio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/configuration.html

Comment: Thank you! But what will differ if I omit the decorator?

Comment: @EgorOsokin: compare 2 versions, they are equivalents and using that decorator is easier version of using the event loop

Answer (score 8):

[Sławomir Lenart's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57463137/840428) is still correct, but note that as of `pytest-asyncio>=0.17` if you add `asyncio_mode = auto` to your `pyproject.toml` or `pytest.ini` there is no need for the marker, i.e. this behaviour is enabled for async tests automatically.

See https://pytest-asyncio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/configuration.html

Comment: You are correct but I think this should be part of the accepted answer, not a separate answer by itself, as it shouldn't become 'the right answer'. I'll try to merge it into the accepted one

Answer (score 1):

> I've tried to run the following code snippet with pytest and
> pytest-asyncio plugin installed and it **"failed"**

Actually the test is not going to get run. Even if you have `pytest` and `pytest-asyncio` installed, it will be **skipped** and you'll see a warning like this in output:

```
================================== warnings summary ====================================
tests.py::test_div
  /Users/.../ PytestUnhandledCoroutineWarning: async def functions are not natively supported and have been skipped.
  You need to install a suitable plugin for your async framework, for example:
    - anyio
    - pytest-asyncio
    - pytest-tornasync
    - pytest-trio
    - pytest-twisted
    warnings.warn(PytestUnhandledCoroutineWarning(msg.format(nodeid)))

-- Docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/how-to/capture-warnings.html
============================= 1 skipped, 1 warning in 0.02s =============================
```

As the [documentation](https://pytest-asyncio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/markers/index.html) says:

> A coroutine or async generator with this marker is treated as a test
> function by pytest.

So you *have to* mark your async functions.

The `@pytest.mark.asyncio` decorator also allows you to specify the `scope` so that some tests can share the same event loop, otherwise each test will run in it’s own event loop:

```py
import asyncio
import pytest

@pytest.mark.asyncio(scope="class")
class TestClassScopedLoop:
    loop: asyncio.AbstractEventLoop

    async def test_remember_loop(self):
        TestClassScopedLoop.loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()

    async def test_this_runs_in_same_loop(self):
        assert asyncio.get_running_loop() is TestClassScopedLoop.loop
```